# Footnotes in tables?

Tags: best-practices, tables, footnotes

I would like to have footnotes in tables, but the `\footnote` command does not work inside a `table` environment.  Googling one finds that this is [a frequently asked question](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-footintab), at least in the UK.  That link contains a list of solutions to the problem, but since the author of the FAQ does not believe that this is good style, no comparison is made between the different methods.

I am sure that there are good typographical reasons why in most situations it is undesirable to have footnotes in tables (although I have never come across them), however I have recently felt the need to do just this in a paper I am currently writing.

Therefore I'd like to ask two questions:

1. What are the arguments against footnotes in tables?
2. If one really must go against the advice in 1., which method (whether considered in the [FAQ above](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-footintab) or not) would you recommend?

Thanks in advance.

#### Added

In response to ShreevatsaR's comment: I do not much care for where the text of the footnote appears.  I do however insist on the footnote marks being attached to the relevant entries in the table, so that I can avoid having to reference "the second entry in the eighth line of the table", etc...

Comment: The author of the FAQ entry distinguishes between (1) table notes, where the "footnote text" appears at the bottom of the table, and (2) "real" footnotes, where it appears at the bottom of the page outside the table. The author expresses his preference for the former; I also feel it makes sense to attach the footnote text to the table itself. This can be achieved by using either `threeparttable` or `ctable`. If you really want footnotes at the bottom of the page, outside the table, I'd just use `tabularx`, if only because it looks like minimal effort among the options.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I think your comment qualifies as an answer...

Comment: For the record, writing philological notes on Chinese prosody, it has been very useful to me to be able to place footnotes (real footnotes, in ShreevatsaR's parlance) on individual Chinese characters or their monosyllabic transcriptions, each of which appears in a single table cell. There is no clearer or more easily examined way that I can find.

Comment: observation: the question is phrased in terms of "tables", which are floats.  it is not really useful even to *try* to set footnotes at the bottom of the page where a float happens to appear.  however, most of the answers seem to relate to footnotes in tabulars (or -alike); whether one likes it or not (i don't) footnotes in tabulars are do-able.  the faq offers options, iirc (as well as suggesting means of creating table notes.

Comment: Suggested duplicate: [Footnote in tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109467/footnote-in-tabular-environment). (technically the other question is not a strict superset --- it doesn't ask for reasons against footnote in table, but none of the answers below list a disadvantage either, as far as I can see.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had this kind of problem about 10 years ago, and no package provided any trick at this time. My solution was the following. I managed `\footnotemark`s and `\footnotetext`s separately. Semantically it is not really satisfactory, but it works quite well. The only problem may be that the table could be placed in another page than the `\footnotetext` :-(

[image: footnotes in hostile environments: compilation result]

```
\section{Footnotes in hostile environments}



\begin{table}[h] 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
O & X\protect\footnotemark & O \\
\hline
X & O\protect\footnotemark & X \\
\hline
X & O & O
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Victory for Gilles\protect\footnotemark}
\end{table}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-2}
\footnotetext{X}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{O}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{happy birthday Gilles ;-)}

bla\raisebox{0.8ex}{\addtocounter{footnote}{1}\scriptsize\thefootnote}\footnotetext{forced test}blabla\footnote{footnote test}

and now, more difficult: two footnotes in a \fbox{hostile\footnotemark environment\footnotemark}~... 
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\footnotetext{or very hostile}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{area}
```

Comment: When hyperref is used, the hyperlinks unfortunately will not point to the right footnotes.

Comment: Very pragmatic solution!

Comment: @Stephen I used the `tablefootnote` package to get around this in the solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35328/200521

Answer (score 30):

You could use the [tablefootnote](http://ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote) package and `\tablefootnote{...}` inside the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ c  c }
Test1\tablefootnote{Footnote 1} & Test2\tablefootnote{Footnote 2} \\ 
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is a table.\label{FirstTable}}
\end{table}

A newpage:

\newpage

and a second page, so that you can see that the hyperlinks really work.

\end{document}
```

Comment: If `rotating` package is used: `tablefootnote` should be after `rotating`.

Comment: Note: If you use `\tablefootnote` not only in a `tabular` but a `table` the footnote can be placed on a different page than the table.

Comment: ...which is not a good thing most of the time.  they not only "can" but "are" placed there.

Answer (score 20):

With the [`threeparttable`s](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/threeparttable.html) you can add table notes. 
[image: Example of threeparttable LaTeX package]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Sample ANOVA table}
     \begin{tabular}{lllll}
        \toprule
        Stubhead & \( df \) & \( f \) & \( \eta \) & \( p \) \\
        \midrule
                 &     \multicolumn{4}{c}{Spanning text}     \\
        Row 1    & 1        & 0.67    & 0.55       & 0.41    \\
        Row 2    & 2        & 0.02    & 0.01       & 0.39    \\
        Row 3    & 3        & 0.15    & 0.33       & 0.34    \\
        Row 4    & 4        & 1.00    & 0.76       & 0.54    \\
        \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item This is where authors provide additional information about
      the data, including whatever notes are needed.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

(Stolen from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13316/7306))

Comment: It'd be great if someone could add a proof-of-concept to this answer.

Comment: This example is good too: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209806/8666

Answer (score 16):

I have just been playing with this and thought my solution just might help somebody else at some point. I wanted the following:

- table notes i.e. notes at the bottom of the tabular, within the `table` environment - not at the bottom of the page;
- automatic numbering of notes within the list of notes;
- automatic numbering of note markers within the table itself;
- numbering with small letters, to avoid any confusion with the Arabic numerals used to number footnotes and in the table and text to track content;
- note markers in the list of notes to be left aligned with text in the first column of the tabular.

My solution involves an unholy mixture of

- `threeparttablex` with option `referable`: this manages the automatic numbering of the note markers, on the basis of labels inserted into the list of notes;
- `enumitem`: to customise the list of notes.

This is a bit complex in terms of number of cooks responsible for the broth. To say that `enumitem` is used to 'customise' the list is a bit misleading. Essentially, my solution redefines it. More specifically, `threeparttable` provides `tablenotes`. `threeparttablex` redefines it and provides `\tnotex{}` and some other enhancements. `enumitem` is then used to redefine `tablenotes` again.

## *Caveat emptor...*

Anyway, for what it is worth:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,booktabs,cfr-lm}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\renewlist{tablenotes}{enumerate}{1}
\makeatletter
\setlist[tablenotes]{label=\tnote{\alph*},ref=\alph*,itemsep=\z@,topsep=\z@skip,partopsep=\z@skip,parsep=\z@,itemindent=\z@,labelindent=\tabcolsep,labelsep=.2em,leftmargin=*,align=left,before={\footnotesize}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering\tlstyle
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Great Value}\\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
      Option    &   Robot 1 &    Robot 2    & Robot 3 & Total\\
      \midrule
      Develop Robot 1 brilliant eye\tnotex{tnote:robots-r1}
      & 5   & 78    & 54    & 56\\
      Develop Robot 2 extended ears\tnotex{tnote:robots-r2}
      & 24  & 87    & 42    & 23\\
      Develop Robot 3 brilliant eye\tnotex{tnote:robots-r3}
      & 0.5 & $\pi$ & 61    & $<19.3$\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item\label{tnote:robots-r1}That is, $360^\circ$ vision, as proposed by Noddy Norris.
      \item\label{tnote:robots-r2}As recommended by \emph{Robot Review}.
      \item\label{tnote:robots-r3}That is, X-Ray vision, as proposed by \emph{Mechanical Maniacs}.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
  \caption{\label{tab:robots}Total values of Jim's technological options for robot projects he thinks possible.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: robot notes in tables]

Answer (score 14):

I think these two Q&A's ought to be merged; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2891556/2153622) (by [dmckee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2509/dmckee)) is my favourite:

> This is a classic difficulty in LaTeX.
>
> The problem is how to do layout with floats (figures and tables, an
> similar objects) and footnotes. In particular, it is hard to pick a
> place for a float with certainty that making room for the associated
> footnotes won't cause trouble. So the standard `tabular`
> and `figure` environments don't even try.
>
> What can you do:
>
> 1. **Fake it.** Just put a hardcoded vertical skip
>    at the bottom of the caption and then write the footnote yourself (use
>    `\footnotesize` for the size). You also have to manage the
>    symbols or number yourself with `\footnotemark`. Simple,
>    but not very attractive, and the footnote does not appear at the
>    bottom of the page.
> 2. Use the `tabularx`,
>    `longtable`, [`threeparttable[x]`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable/)
>    (kudos to [Joseph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888817/footnotes-for-tables-in-latex/2890759#2890759))
>    or [`ctable`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ctable/)
>    which support this behavior.
> 3. [Manage
>    it by hand.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888817/footnotes-for-tables-in-latex/2888869#2888869) Use `[h!]` (or `[H]` with the
>    float package) to control where the float will appear, and
>    `\footnotetext` on the same page to put the footnote where
>    you want it. Again, use `\footnotemark` to install the
>    symbol. Fragile and requires hand-tooling every instance.
> 4. The
>    `footnote` package provides the `savenote`
>    environment, which can be used to do this.
> 5. Minipage it (code
>    [stolen
>    outright](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ftncapt), and read the discalimer about long caption texts in that
>    case):
>
> ```
>     \begin{figure}
>       \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
>         ...
>         \caption[Caption for LOF]%
>           {Real caption\footnote{blah}}
>       \end{minipage}
>     \end{figure}
> ```
>
> Additional reference: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-footintab.

Answer (score 5):

Imho, I don't see any specific reason not to put footnotes in a table; however, if the content of the footnotes can be explained in the caption of the table itself, I'd prefer to use the caption. I'm used to write in the caption a short explanation of what in the table is, rather than a short title.

I suggest you to use the `ctable` package, using the `\tnote` command.
From the package documentation:

> The ctable package lets you easily typeset captioned table and ﬁgure ﬂoats with optional footnotes.

At page 3 of the documentation the `\tnote` command is explained, and at page 4  you can see a clear example.

Answer (score 4):

You can add table footnotes in `talltblr` or `longtblr` environments of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray).

```
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{talltblr}[
    caption = {A Simple Table},
    label = {talltblr:test},
    note{a} = {First Footnote.},
    note{b} = {Second Footnote.},
    remark{Note} = {Some Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Text.},
    remark{Source} = {Some Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Text.},    
  ]{XXXXX}
    \toprule
        Head  & A   & B                 & C                & D   \\
    \midrule
        Row 1 & 1   & 0.67\TblrNote{a}  & 0.55             & 0.41 \\
        Row 2 & 2   & 0.02              & 0.01             & 0.39 \\
        Row 3 & 3   & 0.15              & 0.33\TblrNote{b} & 0.34 \\
        Row 4 & 4   & 1.00              & 0.76             & 0.54 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The commands `\savenotes` and `\spewnotes` from the [`footnote` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/threeparttable.html) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has its own built-in command `\tabularnote` and many possibilities of customization.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,enumitem,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hb]
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{1ex}
\centering
\caption{Use of \texttt{\textbackslash tabularnote}\tabularnote{It's possible
    to put a note in the caption.}}
\label{t:tabularnote}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}llc@{}}[notes/bottomrule, 
   tabularnote = Some text before the notes.] 
\toprule
Last name & First name & Length of life \\
\midrule
Churchill & Wiston &  91\\
Nightingale\tabularnote{Considered as the first nurse of
history.}\tabularnote{Nicknamed ``the Lady with the Lamp''.} 
& Florence & 90 \\
Schoelcher & Victor & 89\tabularnote{The label of the note is overlapping.}\\
Touchet & Marie & 89 \\
Wallis & John & 87 \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use define a footnote *outside* the table/tabular by using a custom command `marklessfootnote`, and *then refer* to it within the table instead.

```
\newcommand\marklessfootnote[1]{
    \addtocounter{footnote}{1}
    \footnotetext{#1}
}
```

The `marklessfootnote` can then be referred to within a table using a regular `\ref` command, or the `cleveref` package command `\cref` with ease, also compatible with `hyperref` package.

**Ref:**

```
%... inside my doc
\marklessfootnote{My footnote \label{ftn:01}}
%... inside my tabular...
\textsuperscript{\tiny\ref{ftn:01}} % With commands to superscript the mark.
```

**Cleveref:**

Note to make Cref link the same style as the regular footnote, you can redefine the format as follows.

```
\crefformat{footnote}{#2\textsuperscript{\footnotemark[#1]}#3} %option to superscript mark.
%... %inside my doc
\marklessfootnote{My footnote \label{ftn:01}}
%... %inside my tabular...
\cref{ftn:01}
```

Comment: Just noticed, the hyperref / ref link displays the right footnote number, but links to the most recently defined footnotetext (with marker) rather than the actual footnotetext (without marker). I think I'm missing a counter here or something. I've tried adding `\addtocounter{Hfootnote}{1}` but haven't solved it yet.