# footnote in the column name of a table

Tags: floats, footnotes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Footnotes in tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1583/footnotes-in-tables)

I tried inserting `\footnote` in the column name of a table. The footnote did not appear at the bottom of the page as expected. Can someone help me?

A sample code is provided below:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline   
      \textbf{Queries} & \textbf{NUR}\footnote{No of unigram models satisfying user 
        preference} & \textbf{NBR}\footnote{No of bigram models satisfying user 
        preference} & \textbf{UCHR}\footnote{class hit rate for unigram models} & 
      \textbf{BCHR}\footnote{class hit rate for bigram models} \
```

Comment: Tables are usually furnished with table notes. If you show some code in form of a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), specific help will be much easier.

Comment: I have uploaded sample code

Comment: read the FAQ: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=footintab

Comment: A full example as requested would be much more helpful.

Comment: Some related/duplicate questions [Footnotes in Tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1583/2693) and [Footnotes in tabulars](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35200/2693).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [tablefootnote](http://ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote) package with `\tablefootnote`s inside the table instead of ordinary `\footnote`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{hyperref}% if you use hyperref, load it before tablefootnote
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline   
      \textbf{Queries} & \textbf{NUR}\tablefootnote{No of unigram models satisfying user 
        preference} & \textbf{NBR}\tablefootnote{No of bigram models satisfying user 
        preference} & \textbf{UCHR}\tablefootnote{class hit rate for unigram models} & 
      \textbf{BCHR}\tablefootnote{class hit rate for bigram models} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

% \newpage
% for making easier the testing of the hyperlinks

\end{document}
```