# How can I find a footnote by its number (Hfootnote.xx)?

Tags: hyperref, errors, footnotes, warnings

I want to find out, which footnote is causing a warning message in my pdfoutput.

I am using Miktex 2.9, my document is from the type "scrreprt" and I make usage of the package parnotes.

I get the message: `{HFootnote.9} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one.`

I know that there are many questions and answers to this topic, but the solutions do not work out for me. I tried the following:

- hyperref is loaded as the last package
- yes, I use footnotes in tables, but that's what the package "parnotes" is good for, isn't it?

I can't provide a minimal example, because then I would know which footnote does cause the error. My document has a size of 250 pages and I do not have the time to check each of the footnotes if it is displayed and linked correctly (I have to finish my Masterthesis in three days).

**Can someone please tell me how I can find out which footnote does cause the trouble?**

Just in case that I somehow misused the parnotes-package in my tables, here is an example of one of my tables (the table and the footnote is displayed correctly):

```
\begin{table}[htbp]                 
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|L{2.5cm}|X|p{11cm}|}
    \toprule
    \parnoteclear
    \textbf{Anforderung} & \textbf{P(5)} & \textbf{Bewertung}\\                 
        \midrule                    
    Preis & / & Some text\parnote{My footnote text.} which has a value of 80~\texteuro\ per month.\\        
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}  
\parnotes                           
\caption{My caption for this table.}
\label{tab:ModelingToolSignavio}                
\end{table}
```

This is the definition of the parnoteclear-command:

```
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[roman]{parnotes}    % enables footnotes in tables

\def\parnoteclear{%
    \gdef\PN@text{}%
    \parnotereset
}
```

Thanks in advance for every hint, idea or advise.
Timo

Comment: Option `verbose` of package `hyperref` writes some infos about anchor settings, links and other stuff into the `.log` file that might help to find the location in the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is produced by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Test\footnote{Footnote text.}.
\begin{table}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    First & Second\footnote{Second footnote.}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{tab:t}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

this time with reference to `{HFootnote.2}`.  The `.2` means that is the second footnote causing the problem.  Cutting and pasting your other code in does not produce the error your  report from the table with a `\parnote`.  So try to track down direct uses of the `\footnote` command in your document.

`hyperref` has all sorts of issues with footnotes.  See the answers to the question [Clickable Table Footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6090/15925), for discussion, why not to do this, and workarounds.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I checked the mentioned file, but there was only one footnote.
So I checked my glossary-entries and I found a reference to another glossary-entry. For the reason, that I mention my glossary entries on first appearance in the footnote-section, this has caused a "footnote in the footnote".

Thank you very much for your help!