# Footnote inside section head: Error when using titlesec and footnotebackref packages

Tags: sectioning, footnotes, titlesec

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}        
\usepackage{footnotebackref} 
\begin{document}
\section{Whatever\protect\footnote{Problematic footnote}}
\end{document}
```

gives an error if both the `titlesec` and `footnotebackref` packages are loaded (while it works as expected if any of them is removed). I tried using `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`, to no avail. Any idea on what might be going on and how to fix it? (I do know using footnotes in heads is not advisable, but anyway...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [How to use the footnotebackref package with \footnotemark and \footnotetext?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78423/how-to-use-the-footnotebackref-package-with-footnotemark-and-footnotetext/), the solution is to use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` with the following redefinition:

```
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro{\BHFN@Old@footnotemark}{\@footnotemark}  
\renewcommand*{\@footnotemark}{%
    \refstepcounter{BackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
    \xdef\BackrefFootnoteTag{bhfn:\theBackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
    \label{\BackrefFootnoteTag}%
    \BHFN@Old@footnotemark
}
\makeatother
```

(One has also to `\protect` the `\footnotemark`). Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}        
\usepackage{footnotebackref} 
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro{\BHFN@Old@footnotemark}{\@footnotemark}
\renewcommand*{\@footnotemark}{%
    \refstepcounter{BackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
    \xdef\BackrefFootnoteTag{bhfn:\theBackrefHyperFootnoteCounter}%
    \label{\BackrefFootnoteTag}%
    \BHFN@Old@footnotemark
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Whatever\protect\footnotemark}
\footnotetext{Problematic footnote}
\end{document}
```

[image]