# footnotebackref leads to error when using footnotes in epigraphs

Tags: footnotes, epigraphs

Adding the `footnotebackref` package leads to compile error when a footnote is used inside an epigraph, as in the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\begin{document}
\epigraph{one\footnotemark}{lala 2023}
\footnotetext{test 123}
Test
\end{document}
```

The error given is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \BackrefFootnoteTag
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Using the solution provided in the duplicate question fixed the issue on my system at least and works correctly: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78438/273733, put the code starting with `\makeatletter` and ending with `\makeatother` in your preamble after your packages and it compiles correctly