# Multiple footmark messes with hyperref. Hyperlinks pointing to wrong footnotes or dead

Tags: hyperref, equations, footnotes

When setting multiple footmarks inside an environment that doesn't allow any (equation), the ids correspond to the correct footnotetexts but not the hyperlinks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    Text\footnote{text1} Text\footnote{text2}

    \begin{equation}
        \refstepcounter{equation}
        J=b a^3
        \tag{\theequation\footnotemark{}\footnotemark{}}
    \end{equation}

    \#1 links to \#1

    \#2 links to \#2

    \#3 does not link anywhere

    \#4 links to \#3

    \addtocounter{footnote}{-2} %3=n
    \stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{a}
    \stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{b}

    \newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) These kind of things are not well handled by `hyperref`. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6092/27635) of lockstep for a workaround.