# Footnote without a marker

Tags: formatting, footnotes

I would like to have a footnote about the funding source of my work in the first page without marker.

I tried below approaches:

1. `\footnotetext{text goes here}`
   This creates a footnote but with '0' as marker. However, the marker reference does not 
   appear within the normal text where I placed this command.
2. Used `\def\blfootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}` definition provided at http://help-csli.stanford.edu/tex/latex-footnotes.shtml#unnumber. I placed this definition in the main tex file just after package declaration.
   But, this gives the below error.

   ```
      ! Use of \@ doesn't match its definition.
      \blfootnote ->\xdef \@thefnmark{}\@f
                                          ootnotetext
   ```

Answer (score 205):

As Stephen mentioned in his answer, if you're using your definition in your `.tex` file, you need to enclose it inside `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`. Another option not involving the use of the special character `@` (thus not requiring `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`) would be to locally redefine `\thefootnote` (taking care of correcting the `footnote` counter):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Some text\blfootnote{A footnote without marker} and some more text\footnote{A standard footnote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. Just looked at your suggestions, but was able to have the footnote working just sometime ago. The problem was that I had to keep the definition of blfootnote in the class file instead of the tex file.

Comment: @Rajesh: as Stephen mentioned in his answer, enclosing your definition with `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` you can keep the definition in the `.tex` file. See also my updated answer for another option not involving internal commands.

Comment: What does "bl" in "blfootnote" stand for?

Comment: @DavidDoria: Gonazalo is re-implementing a macro that the original poster copied from a [resource](http://help-csli.stanford.edu/tex/latex-footnotes.shtml#unnumber) that is no longer available.  So we'll never know what `bl` stands for.  One may guess “*bl*ind”, but the important think is that it be different from `\footnote`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina with the solution you have proposed hyper-link will provide and empty market were I place `\blfootnote{}`. Is there any way to continue to use hyper-link that provide links for the other footnotes and references but at the same time have just a note for the desired blfootnote?

Comment: This solution creates an empty highlighted link when using the hyperref package. This solution avoids that: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250221/supressing-the-footnote-number?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: How can I get rid of the indention which is left at the place of the footnotemark?

Comment: Note that this solution does not work when \blfootnote is inside \title{}. In this case the symbol is still printed in the footnote (but not in the title).

Answer (score 51):

In some cases, you might want to suppress the number on a footnote. I looked around the web, and a few suggestions were out there, but the simplest one I could find was the following:

```
\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{Put your text here}
```

Comment: This may work, but it is not really LaTeX style and may have serious side-effects, e.g., when switching back to normal footnotes.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863). I did not edit your answer just for this detail, you might want to change it yourself.

Comment: Brutal but effective. For short documents without other footnotes this is the best!
I think half of it should go in the preamble and the acutal not in the document. I hop you don't mind me editing your answer.

Comment: It is probably a good idea to save the original defintion of `\footnote` to be able to switch back to the previous state if needed. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170511/47927

Answer (score 44):

`@` is a special character in (La)TeX. Enclose your code with `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother
```

---

**Edit** (from my former comments):

Internal commands with `@` can be used without `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in the class file (as you found out) as well as in style files, too. Only in the `.tex` file the "envelope" is needed. That said, I would prefer Gonzalo Medina's answer over my own (or your placement of the redefinition in the class file) because it only locally redefines footnote (respectively give a new command for unnumbered footnotes).

When you are using the [hyperref](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package, you would probably want to add `\addtocounter{Hfootnote}{-1}%` to the code of GM, otherwise it will work but error messages about (hyper)footnotes will become tricky, because e.g. `Hfootnote 42` then is `footnote 41` - use `\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}` without `\addtocounter{Hfootnote}{-1}` for several cases, and the difference between `footnote` and `Hfootnote` makes debugging harder than necessary.

**Edit** (again):

As suggested by egreg, I changed `\xdef` (=`\global\edef`) to `\gdef` (=`\global\def`), because there is no need to **e**xpand the **def**inition's content here (as it is just empty).

Comment: `\xdef` should be `\gdef`; it doesn't make any difference here, it could in other situations.

Comment: +1, @Gonzalo Medina solution doesn't work 'well' with hyperref package, it lets an empty link box to the footnote!

Comment: This is a better approach, because it only uses the footnotetext, not occupying space for the footnotemark.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is an old question, but the answers from both Gonzalo Medina and Stephen may interact poorly with hyperref. I did not test the titlefoot package but, from my limited understanding of the LaTeX code, it seems it may not be immune either.

Apparently, however, we are "safe" by using @xfootnotenext, as hyperref's implementation of it delegates to the default LaTeX footnote code. And it is simple to do so, just call \footnotetext with an optional parameter. To do that, switch footnote markers temporarily to symbols and select 0 as the symbol. Nothing gets printed (no symbol for 0), nothing gets added to the text (we are just using footnotetext), and hyperref does not try to add anchors or links.

```
\newcommand\extrafootertext[1]{%
    \bgroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
    \renewcommand\thempfootnote{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}%
    \footnotetext[0]{#1}%
    \egroup
}
```

Comment: Indeed, with hyper-ref highlighting references, the accepted answer shows a "square" link marker from where \blfootnote is used. This answer works better as it doesn't add any marker where \extrafootertext is used.

Answer (score 6):

There’s also an old package, `titlefoot`, which has no documentation except a few comments in the `.sty` file. It provides a command, `\unmarkedfntext{...}`, which has never caused problems in my documents.  A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,titlefoot}
\title{My Brilliant Article}
\author{Me}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\maketitle\unmarkedfntext{Originally published by Oxford.}

\blindtext\footnote{It seems to play well with hyperref.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems causing some issues for me. All the figures are moved to the end of the document after adding `\unmarkedfntext`. A regular footnote would not cause so.

Comment: I like this answer the best, because, as you said, it plays well with hyperref.  Other "markerless footnote" solutions I tried left a little blank box in the text (i.e., a link attached to the blank marker).

Comment: I had only one problem with the definition the command `\keywords`, apparently the command is already defined in the package, so I had to change the name. However, I find this "package"-solution more elegant that own defined functions. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `\footnotemark[0]` and `\footnotetext[0]{Footnote text}` pair. The `[0]` will suppress the label.

Comment: This is only true if `\thefootnote` is set to `\roman{footnote}` or `\Roman{footnote}`.

Comment: And it's `\footnotemark`, not "marker.

Comment: It did not work for me (in amsart style).

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but just so there is an answer in plain tex, in plain tex you can just do `\footnote{}{Footnote without a marker}`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried previous answers several times but did not work. I am working on the AIAA template and the solution was this simple:

```
\footnote[]{Footnote without number.}
```

Comment: Didn't work for the template I'm working on

Comment: This moved my title downwards on an AIAA template. \footnotetext[0]{Footnote text} worked though.

Comment: This does not work for normal classes like `article`. Then you get `Missing number, treated as zero`.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to remove the in-line mark, yet keep the number in the footnote, you can define a custom `\marklessfootnote` command.

```
\newcommand\marklessfootnote[1]{
    \addtocounter{footnote}{1} %no call is made to \footnotemark.
    \footnotetext{#1}
}
```

This may be useful for those wanting to define a footnote to refer to in a table (see [Q1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1583/137109), [Q2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109467/137109)), where there are common problems. The markless footnote can then be referred to in a table using a regular `\ref` command, or the `cleveref` package command `\cref` with ease, also compatible with `hyperref` package.

**Ref:**

```
%... inside my doc
\marklessfootnote{My footnote \label{ftn:01}}
%... inside my tabular...
\textsuperscript{\tiny\ref{ftn:01}} % With commands to superscript the mark.
```

**Cleveref:**

Note to make Cref link the same style as the regular footnote, you can redefine the format as follows:

```
\crefformat{footnote}{#2\textsuperscript{\footnotemark[#1]}#3} %optional to superscript mark.
%... %inside my doc
\marklessfootnote{My footnote \label{ftn:01}}
%... %inside my tabular...
\cref{ftn:01}
```

Comment: Need to fix hyperref link to markless footnote, as commented on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/695113/137109) post.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Shukla's answer, one can do

```
{\def\thefootnote{}\footnotetext{Put your text here}}
```

so that the definition of `\thefootnote`
will reset outside the local group.

Anothery hacky way is

```
\footnotetext[0\def\thefoornote{}]{Your footnote here}
```

This will also nullify the printing command.
This is only temporary
(because things in `[]` are put in a local group.)