# How do I add an acknowledgement to author as numbered footnote and a footnote to title as symbol footnote?

Tags: numbering, footnotes

I need to add a footnote with a * to the title and begin numbered footnotes with the aknowledgements. I have seen individual solutions to all these but never the combination.

So far I have attempted this combination:

```
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\@fnsymbol}{\@arabic}{}{}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}{}{}{}

\newcommand{\footstar}[1]{$^*$\footnotetext{$^*$#1}}
\title{TITLE \footstar{Manuscript received February 2012; revised May 2013.}}

\author{AUTHOR \thanks{THANKS} \\ INSTITUTION}
```

However, when I do this I get a '0' before the '*' footnote.

Comment: You usually need to hook into the `.cls`' mechanism for doing `\thanks`.  So it is helpful if you provide more information in the form of a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or *\or 1\or 2\or
   3\or 4\or 5\or 6\or 7\or 8\else\@ctrerr\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{TITLE \footnote{Manuscript received February 2012; revised May 2013.}}

\author{AUTHOR \thanks{THANKS} \\ INSTITUTION}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Anyway, I don't recommend such a use of footnote marks, since one can get confused on later footnotes.

Probably, something like

```
\makeatletter
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or *\or a\or b\or
   c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\else\@ctrerr\fi}}
\makeatother
```

that results in using `*` in the title and letters for `\thanks` commands is better, as you can see with the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or *\or a\or b\or
   c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\else\@ctrerr\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{TITLE \footnote{Manuscript received February 2012; revised May 2013.}}

\author{AUTHOR \thanks{THANKS} \\ INSTITUTION}

\maketitle

Some text\footnote{1st real footnote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not a fan of this type of footnoting either but the journal I am submitting to requires this. I have also just noticed that this sequence of commands counts the first * as a footnote. Is there a way to exclude the * in the footnote count?

Comment: @diplodocuscoffeespot Not with this approach. Why do you need this?

Comment: Journal wants the footnotes to be like this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I have dealt with this issue As @karlkoeller suggested I used this in the preamble and then I reset the footnote counter to start from "2" in the main body. This is a pretty rough and ready way to get this, I think.

```
\makeatletter
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or *\or 1\or 2\or
   3\or 4\or 5\or 6\or 7\or 8\else\@ctrerr\fi}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\title{TITLE \footnote{Manuscript received February 2012; revised May 2013.}}

\author{AUTHOR\thanks{THANKS}}

\section{INTRODUCTION}
{\setcounter{footnote}{1}}{}{}{}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a less LaTeX-way solution, but it on the other hand gives you a complete flexibility:

1. We need a footnote that has no symbols whatsoever.

`\usepackage{lipsum}`

```
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup

  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup }
```

See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30726/64479) answer for more details.

2. Just put a footnote without a marker wherever you want, but on the same page, adding the marker inside of the footnote text and adjusting the alignment: 
   `\blfootnote{\hspace*{-7.4pt}$\dagger$ Your Acknowledgements here}`
3. Add the marker using math language: 
   `My Title $^\dagger$`

---

Again, I know this is not how LaTeX is supposed to work, but on the other hand you should do it only for the title page, plus the proposed solution gives you a complete flexibility on what, how, and where you can put as a footnote.