# How do I remove citation number from footcite

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing, biber

How can I display footnote citations with only the citation text without any footnote number (and also remove it in the text). For example, I would like to get the following footnote (MWE follows):

> ---
>
> Doe 2013, Public 2013

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Doe2013,
        title   = {Lorem Ipsum},
        volume  = {1},
        journal = {J. Foo},
        author  = {J. Doe},
        year    = {2013},
        pages   = {1--10},
    }

    @article{Public2013,
        title   = {Dolor Sit Amet},
        volume  = {1},
        journal = {J. Foo},
        author  = {J. Q. Public},
        year    = {2013},
        pages   = {11--20},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./test.bib}

\begin{document}
    \footcite{Doe2013,Public2013}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is to redefine the `\blx@mkbibfootnote` command that is defining citation in footnote. You can the use a modified version of the `\footnote` command, with no number.

[Redefinition of the `\footnote` command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker):

```
\newcommand\footnotenonun[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}
```

Redefinition of the `\blx@mkbibfootnote` command:

```
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd{\blx@mkbibfootnote}[2]{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\blx@warning{Nested notes}%
     \addspace\mkbibparens{#2}}
    {\unspace
     \ifnum\blx@notetype=\tw@
       \expandafter\@firstoftwo
     \else
       \expandafter\@secondoftwo
     \fi
       {\csuse{blx@theendnote#1}{\protecting{\blxmkbibnote{end}{#2}}}}
       {\csuse{footnotenonum#1}{\protecting{\blxmkbibnote{foot}{#2}}}}}}
\makeatother
```

The good point is that it won't interfeer with footnote numbering if you use the "normal" `\footnote` command. Of course, if you want all your footnotes without number, you can `\renewcommand` the `\footnote` command instead of creating a new one.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Doe2013,
        title   = {Lorem Ipsum},
        volume  = {1},
        journal = {J. Foo},
        author  = {J. Doe},
        year    = {2013},
        pages   = {1--10},
    }

    @article{Public2013,
        title   = {Dolor Sit Amet},
        volume  = {1},
        journal = {J. Foo},
        author  = {J. Q. Public},
        year    = {2013},
        pages   = {11--20},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand\footnotenonum[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd{\blx@mkbibfootnote}[2]{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\blx@warning{Nested notes}%
     \addspace\mkbibparens{#2}}
    {\unspace
     \ifnum\blx@notetype=\tw@
       \expandafter\@firstoftwo
     \else
       \expandafter\@secondoftwo
     \fi
       {\csuse{blx@theendnote#1}{\protecting{\blxmkbibnote{end}{#2}}}}
       {\csuse{footnotenonum#1}{\protecting{\blxmkbibnote{foot}{#2}}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \footcite{Doe2013,Public2013} test\footnote{test}, test\footnotenonum{test2}, test\footcite{Doe2013}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
Obtained after running `pdflatex test.tex` (there are BibTeX warnings, one may launch `biber test` then rerun `pdflatex test.tex` but it works however).

[image]

[image]

Comment: It removes the citation number, but it's no longer a footnote... It's cited in the main body.

Comment: I added the MWE I used to test it, and the resulting output.

Comment: The MWE doesn't answer the question. It literately prints Doe2013 and does not cite the article properly.

Comment: You have to run biber after the first latex run to get the proper result (which is different from the shown output.)

Comment: Can you be more specific? I've just retried and everything is still working (as it was 8 years ago). A quick'n'dirty test (just running `pdflatex test.pdf` is giving the output I gave at the time. I don't remember getting the BibTeX warning -- now I do have it to -- but runnng `biber` and re-running `pdflatex` I get almost the same output (no bold on references, that's all). I guess I had assume people reading the answer would have some familiarity with LaTeX/BibTeX; I'll add the commands to get the ouptut in the text.

Comment: The bold output means that the citations weren't found. But at least on my machine that is only due to the file name mismatch between `\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}` and `\addbibresource{./test.bib}`. If the file name happens to be `test.tex` things work, but to make the file universally usable `\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}` and `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` would be more appropriate. With that changed the MWE does exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Ah right for the bold citations, I forgot about that, thanks for pointing it out. Thank you also for the suggestion; I changed de MWE accordingly.