# Insert ams classification in scrartcl

Tags: math-mode, footnotes, koma-script

How should I insert the AMS classification in the bottom of the first page ?

Google doesn't seem to say anything.

EDIT:
Here is the requested code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,numbers=withendperiod]{scrartcl} 

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\blfootnote{\textup{2000} \textit{Mathematics Subject Classification}: \textup{11D72}} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hum, are you sure you have posted all the code that is sufficient to reproduce your problem? I am wondering if you have some modified definition of `\deffootnote` and `\deffootnotemark`? KOMA controls the presentation of footnotes in two different places, one is via `\thefootnotemark` which the code I gave suppresses, the other is via the formatting options in `\deffootnote`. It is possible that somewhere in your workflow the footnote presentation is redefined so that the footnote definition is something like `\thefootnotemark)`, which will cause you to see what you saw.

Comment: not really relevant to the question, but you should be citing the (current) *2010* classification, not 2000.

Answer (score 2):

The `\subjclass` command is defined in the `ams` class files, that is, it is defined in `amsart.cls` and `amsbook.cls` etc. In other words, it is not something you load from a package.

It essentially just sets a footnote. So you can follow [this answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker) to get a footnote without a marker, and just put in as the footnote text

```
\textup{2000} \textit{Mathematics Subject Classification}: \textup{<insert MSC here>}
```

---

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blfootnote{\textup{2000} \textit{Mathematics Subject Classification}:
code}
\end{document}
```

Which outputs on the bottom of the page:

[image]

---

*Edit:* It seems that the OP uses a different option for the presentation of the footnotes: I generally just use superscripts, but it appears that the OP may prefer numbers followed by a parenthesis. Here's a version that would allow that:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}
\deffootnote{0em}{1.6em}{\expandafter\ifdefempty\expandafter{\thefootnotemark}{}{\thefootnotemark)\enskip}}


\begin{document}
\blfootnote{\textup{2000} \textit{Mathematics Subject Classification}:
code}
\footnote{Normal footnote}
\end{document}
```

In this version `etoolbox` is used to conditionally set the parenthesis mark depending on whether `\thefootnotemark` is empty or not (the `\expandafters` are just kludged-together hacks since `\ifdefempty` doesn't expand all the way down, and it appears that `\thefootnotemark` expands to a macro which expands to a macro which expands to the empty string, so without the `\expandafter` the test fails). The output looks like this:

[image]

To further customise and tune using the `\deffootnote` command, please see [the KOMA script guide](http://www.komascript.de/files/scrguien.pdf).

Comment: This doesn't work sufficiently well, by which I mean that although a number does not appear in the footnote, the parenthesis sign ")" appears in its place.  Any other suggestions ?

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"? Does it not show up? Do you get an error?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my previous answer.

Comment: What parenthesis sign? Please edit your original post with a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) showing the problem. With just a vanilla `scrartcl` document and using the code from [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30723/119) I don't see any parenthesis signs.

Comment: Thank you Willie, again the same problem appears with the code you give: Instead of "2000 Mathematics...code" at the end of the page, there appears ")2000 Mathematics...code"

Comment: which makes me think that your solution is not the natural one

Comment: @manenir: I tried the code you posted. There are no parentheses. Which distribution of TeX are you using? Which version of koma-script?

Comment: Hmmm, how do I find out which versions do I use ? cheers

Comment: The version is included in the logs, when you, for example, issue `latex filename.tex`. There would be a line that says something like `Document Class: scrartcl 2012/05/15 v3.11 KOMA-Script document class (article)`

Comment: I tried your second suggestion ( the one with \usepackage{etoolbox} etc.)
and everything works nice APART from the fact that a new problem emerges: A parenthesis ")" appears in the mathematical text at the middle of the page
at the place where the blfootnote command appears in the latex file. Any suggestions ?