# Footnotes without numbering

Tags: numbering, footnotes

I have used the following "no numbering command" for footnotes:

```
\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{some text}
```

to insert a footnote without number (just once). However, now all my footnotes appear without numbers. What's the counter command to cancel the "no numbering command" after I put it?

Thanks

Comment: Please see my final revision that allows the usage `\footnote[]{footnote text}` to create an unnumbered footnote.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to save (using `\let`) the original definition and reinstate it afterwards.  Also, I decrement the footnote counter, so that the blank footnote doesn't increment the index.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote
\textheight 1in
\begin{document}
First Footnote,%
\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{some text}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\let\thefootnote\svthefootnote
next footnote\footnote{some more text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `\footnotetext` for the blank footnote, and then you don't have to reset the footnote counter (but you still have to reinstate the definition of `\thefootnote`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote
\textheight 1in
\begin{document}
First Footnote,%
\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{some text}
\let\thefootnote\svthefootnote
next footnote\footnote{some more text}
\end{document}
```

Putting this all together, you can make it into a macro, `\blankfootnote{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote
\textheight 1in
\newcommand\blankfootnote[1]{%
  \let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{#1}%
  \let\thefootnote\svthefootnote%
}
\begin{document}
First Footnote,\blankfootnote{some text}
next footnote\footnote{some more text}
\end{document}
```

---

And now, for the coup de grace, one can redefine the definition of `\footnote`, so that the syntax `\footnote[]{my footnote}`, which would otherwise break LaTeX, now is made to call on `\blankfootnote` automagically.  This way, you don't need to remember the separate command `\blankfootnote`, but rather just use `\footnote` with an explicitly blank optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote
\textheight 1in
\newcommand\blankfootnote[1]{%
  \let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{#1}%
  \let\thefootnote\svthefootnote%
}
\let\svfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnote[2][?]{%
  \if\relax#1\relax%
    \blankfootnote{#2}%
  \else%
    \if?#1\svfootnote{#2}\else\svfootnote[#1]{#2}\fi%
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
First Footnote,\footnote[]{some text}
next footnote\footnote{some more text}
Force footnote number 5 here\footnote[5]{special footnote}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Steven, is it possible also to suppress the line / horizontal rule?

Comment: @Mathemanic `\let\footnoterule\relax`

Comment: That worked. Thank you!