# footnote for thesis chapter without mark or numbering (with hyperref used)

Tags: footnotes

I am trying to write my thesis and want to have footnote like "This chapter is adapted from XXX publication" on the first page of each chapter, without the subscript number and the number at the beginning of the footnote as well (since `hyperref` package is used, I also want to make sure that there is no red box appearing).  Does anyone have idea what might be a good way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this help: [Footnotes without numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170511)?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the information!  It seems that this approach would create weird spacing between Chapter name and the main text, as if there is some mark there, which is not good.

Comment: In fact, if you enter such a footnote between the chapter title and the beginning of the text, there *is* something there conceptually.  You have to attach the input for the unnumbered footnote somewhere where it won't be noticed.  Right after the first word of the text should work.  This is something of a hack but providing a "dedicated" technique (such as that used for the unnumbered footnotes at the bottom of the first page with `amsart`) is rather involved and requires knowing what document class you're using, and you haven't told us that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks!  There is another issue: there will be a small red square box (although no number in it) if I enable hyperref package, I am wondering if there is any way to avoid that?

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that; it makes things more complicated.  That's important -- please edit into your question a mention that `hyperref` will be used.  Actually, a different approach might be possible -- define a different footer for the first page, and put the information there.  Will there be any "real" footnotes on those pages?

Comment: @barbarabeeton May I know what it means by "define a different footer for the first page"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106440/discussion-between-barbara-beeton-and-username123).