# Footnotes without numbering and without horizontal rule

Tags: numbering

This is similar to Footnotes without numbering question here [Footnotes without numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170511/footnotes-without-numbering) but it won't let me add a comment and this isn't an answer..

When I add \let\footnoterule\relax as in order to suppress the horizontal rule as suggested in the comment to the answer, such as this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote
\textheight 1in
\newcommand\blankfootnote[1]%
  {%
  \let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{#1}%
  \let\footnoterule\relax%
  \let\thefootnote\svthefootnote%
  }%
\let\svfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnote[2][?]%
  {%
  \if\relax#1\relax%
    \blankfootnote{#2}%
  \else%
    \if?#1\svfootnote{#2}\else\svfootnote[#1]{#2}\fi%
  \fi
  }
\begin{document}
First Footnote here\footnote[]{footnote 1} next footnote\footnote{footnote 2}
Force footnote number 5 here\footnote[5]{footnote 3 numbered 5}.

Another\footnote[]{footnote 4} footnote here.

And foot note\footnote{footnote 5} 5 here.
\end{document}
```

It suppresses the horizontal rule for all footnotes.  How can I suppress the horizontal rule for some footnotes but not others?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead put the fragment into a compilable minimal document that people can play with. Also, you can format code by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` icon.

Comment: You might look at footmisc and manyfoot packages.  Manyfoot creates different types of footnotes, usually with different formats or counters.  It can also add extra rules between types of footnotes.  So it the dafault rule is turned off and the unnumbered is first, you might get a rule only before the second (numbered) type of footnote.  Or you could just use a bottom float.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=cmt,placement=b]{Comment}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{3}% max bottom floats per page
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{\begin{Comment}\normalfont\footnotesize\parindent=\bibindent #1\end{Comment}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Comment here\comment{First comment} plus some more text.

\lipsum[1-5]

Second comment.\comment{Second comment}

First footnote.\footnote{First footnote.}

\lipsum[6-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice innovative suggestion....`+1`