# How do I mirror bibliography entries at the foot of the page?

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer

I would like to be able to cite an item during the body text and have the reference appear not only in the final bibliography, but also in full with the same bibliography number at the foot of the current page. Although I can generate something close using `/footcite`, it's no good because it's using a completely different numbering system. I'd like to also suppress the appearance of the references beyond their first citation, so that they only appear at the foot of the page when they are initially mentioned.

I've seen this format used in many journals, but I'm going around in circles trying to find where to start. If anyone could point me in the direction of the most appropriate package—or even equip me with the right terminology—I'd be very grateful.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide/link to an image or two that shows this style?  It is not common across all disciplines.

Comment: @jon I've added a screenshot from the well known Russian Journal of Inorganic Chemistry. I guess 'many journals' was an overstatement..

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen this style before but if you want to cite full bibliography entries, you can use the `\fullcite` command of [`biblatex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

My straight forward approach:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multicol,blindtext,xifthen}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\bibliography{literature.bib}

%\newcommand\boxlength{5ex}

\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt} % distance of two-column texts
\newcommand\faligned[2]{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{#1}}%
    {#2}% if \boxlength has not been defined
    {\makebox[#1][l]{#2}}% if \boxlength has been defined
}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \endgroup
}

\newcommand\footquote[1]{%
    \blfootnote{\faligned{\boxlength}{\cite{#1}} \fullcite{#1}}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \blindtext\cite{heisenberg}
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\subsection{Subsection}]
    \blindtext\cite[chpt.∼3]{chomsky}
\end{multicols}

\footquote{heisenberg}
\footquote{chomsky}    

\printbibliography % optional

\end{document}
```

with `literature.bib`

```
@book{chomsky,
title={Biological foundations of language},
author={Lenneberg, Eric H and Chomsky, Noam and Marx, Otto},
volume={68},
year={1967},
publisher={Wiley New York}
}

@incollection{heisenberg,
title={Quantum theory of fields and elementary particles},
author={Heisenberg, Werner},
booktitle={Scientific Review Papers, Talks, and Books Wissenschaftliche {\"U}bersichtsartikel, Vortr{\"a}ge und B{\"u}cher},
pages={552--561},
year={1984},
publisher={Springer}
}
```

compiled with

```
pdflatex document.tex
biber document
pdflatex document.tex
pdflatex document.tex
```

gives something like this:
[image: Rendered MWE]

- [`\blfootnote`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker) suppresses the footnote numbering and
- `\faligned{\boxlength}{`*`foo`*`}` puts *foo* into a box with the width of the value of `\boxlength`, if it has been defined. This allows some additional spacing between `\cite` and `\fullcite` or aligns the `\fullcite`.
- `\footquote{`*`foo`*`}` combines both, where *foo* is the bib-entry.

`\boxlength` with `5ex`:
[image: With extra space]

I thought the box to be useful especially for `style=alphabetic`

[image: extra space alpha]

Take the [`dblfnote`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/yafoot/yafoot-man.pdf) package for two-column footnotes.

I don't exactly understand what you mean by "*suppress[ing] the appearance of the references beyond their first citation*".

If you just want it to appear inside the footnote and **not** in the bibliography, you probably have to set it by hand. Therefore you could have a look at the `thebibliography` environment but as a general principle, I think this to be a very bad idea.