# Supressing the footnote number

Tags: footnotes

How can you remove the footnote number? I am curerntly using `\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote` but it only removes the number from the cited text not the footnote text. So if I do `ABCDE\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{Text}` ABCDE will have no footnote number but at the footnote the number will appear

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is the use of omitting the number (or the symbol)?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can either use:

```
{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{{There is no number in this footnote}}}
```

Or define a macro in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother
```

Then use `\blfootnote{}` as you would use the standard command. Alternatively, you can also use a`\newcommand`, see [Gonzalo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30726/4778).

**Text**

[image]

**Footnotes**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is a text\footnote{dummy} about your question.\blfootnote{No number here!}

And now another dummy to show the numbering.\footnote{Another dummy}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I also remove the space in front of the footnote? So I now have:  <space> footnote text at the bottom

Comment: Thanks! The second solution conveniently avoids the problem of creating an empty highlighted link when using \usepackage{hyperref}.