# Alignment of footnotes with suppressed numbering

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes, book-design

Following the answer to questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250221/supressing-the-footnote-number/250222#250222), I have been using footnotes without a marker and without numbering throughout my publication, like in the MWE below. However, I would now like to align the numberless footnotes to the left; to the place where the numbers are aligned for those footnotes that have a marker. How do I accomplish this?

```
\documentclass[10pt, paper=156mm:235mm, BCOR=12mm, headings=optiontotocandhead, headings=openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Alegreya,AlegreyaSans} 
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\AlegreyaOsF #1}}

\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\KOMAoptions{footnotes=multiple}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000 
\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{\color{lightgray}\thefootnotemark\ \ }
\setkomafont{footnote}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\raggeddictumtext}{\raggedleft}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@schapter}{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter one}
\kant[1-2]\blfootnote{\newline I would like the text of this numberless footnote to align all the way to the left. \newline}\footnote{So that the above numberless footnote aligns to where the number of this footnote aligns.}\kant[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: Adjusting alignment footnotes]

Comment: The `\documentclass` statement is missing in your source code.

Comment: Does any answer [in here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650600/how-to-add-copyright-information-at-the-bottom-of-chapter-page/650604?noredirect=1#comment1621479_650604)  solves your problem?

Comment: Thank you @HeikoTheißen, I have corrected this.

Comment: Thank you, @Celdor - that was indeed useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\deffootnote`  within the definition to change the structure. The footnotemark at the beginning of each footnote is set to a box. In your case this is set to the width of 1em. Easiest would be to redefine it locally which requires you to define `\blfootnote` to use an argument.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{\begingroup
   \deffootnote{0pt}{0pt}{}%
   \let\@thefnmark\relax
   \@footnotetext{#1}
\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

In case you want the second line using the indent, you can use the optional argument for the label width and the required ones to the same value as you do for the standard footnotes, like this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{\begingroup%
   \deffootnote[0pt]{1em}{1em}{}%
   \let\@thefnmark\relax%
   \@footnotetext{#1}%
\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

The arguments are described in detail in the koma-script documentation.