# How to put a footnote in the title in LyX

Tags: lyx, footnotes, titles

I would like an unmarked footnote in my title. When I enter the footnote in the title, it does not appear in my PDF. How can I insert an unmarked footnote in the title which appears on the bottom of the first page?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{{\normalsize{}}\thanks{ABC}{\normalsize{}Title}}\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with ‘ an `unmarked` footnote’?

Comment: with `amsart`, the `\thanks` command (associated with an author, not the title) gives an unmarked footnote at the bottom of the first page.  this command and its associated text should be entered *after* the author, not within the `\author` argument.

Comment: @Bernard I don't want a number or asterisk to appear in the PDF that refers to the footnote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: mwe]

If you want a unmarked footnote in the first page, do not use a LyX footnote within the title ( = `\thanks{}`) but a `\footnotetext{}` in a  ERT box. It can work better (i.e., wihout small caps) after the `\maketitle` in the first line of the normal text environment.

To avoid the mark (`0` in this case) you can  `\let\thefootnote\relax` (i.e, `\thefootnote` do nothing)  but only for this `\footnotetext` if you want normal footnotes after that. See [Footnote without a marker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker) for another ways.

LaTeX version:

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{amsart}
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm,paperheight=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\title{My AMSART Title}
\maketitle
{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{This is my unmarked footnote.}}
My article text.%
\footnote{A marked footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't realize there was a "Thanks" option in Front Matter. If using this mode, the outcome is an unmarked footnote on page 1.