# How to make a footnote of this kind?

Tags: footnotes

How to make a footnote text similar to the one made by this author:

[image]

I tried using `\footnotetext[]{text}` but I get the number 0 before the text. Any ideas?

PS. I just want to write the AMS Subject Classification and the Keywords, not the note mentioned above that text.

Comment: Probably `\thanks{text}` in the argument to `\author`.

Comment: @smillig I do not want a star in the footnote. Please read the edited the question. And egreg I tried using your code but it just prints text next to the author's name.

Comment: The answer to this question is given on the following [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker).