# How to add sth in the footnote space without pointing at anything

Tags: footnotes, acronyms, multicolumn

I know I didn't well describe the problem. Just look at the picture followed. I want to ask how to write that paragraph in where the footnotes are but it is not really a footnote because it doesn't point at anything in the body of the text.

[image]

Comment: This is answered http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker

Answer (score 0):

`\footnotetext {This is a footnote}`

Comment: Thank you. If you don't mind I want to ask a question related. By this way I get the footnote always under other footnotes which point to the text. What could I do to change the order to get, like in the screenshoot up there, the footnote without number on top of other footnotes with numbers?

Comment: The order of footnotes is determined by the order they are entered.