# No numbered & No indented footnotes

Tags: footnotes, indentation

I have been using Stepehn's answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker) to get a new footnote command with no numbering. However, I'd like to get no indentation on the footnote, also. That is: I want `\blfootnote` to have no numbers and no indentation (there are related questions out there, but none of them addresses this double issue together, I think). You can find a MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hi there! I'm using whatsapp!\blfootnote{Though not much...}

\end{document}
```

How can I get what I desire? Thank you all very much in advance.

**EDIT**

Following the comments, I need to further specify the question. I need the non-indented and non-numbered blfootnotes only inside mdframed boxes. I never thought that could make a difference, and given the need for real minimal MWEs and maximum generality, I never specified it in my original question. I'm sorry. A new MWE would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
Hi there! I'm using whatsapp\blfootnote{Though not much...}.
\end{mdframed}

Hi there! I'm using whatsapp\footnote{Though not much...}.
\end{document}
```

Hence, footnotes inside the box should be non-numbered and non-indented; those outside the box should remain as they are.

Thank you all again.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}`.  See chapter 1.10 and 1.11 in http://vesta.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc/footmisc.pdf .

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unluckily, though, your suggestion will change the indentation of all footnotes (including the command `\footnote`, which should remain as it is with no changes). I only want those footnotes written using `\blfootnote` to be non-indented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load package `manyfoot`, but then you have to use a suffix instead a prefix for the additional footnote type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\SetFootnoteHook{\hspace*{-1.8em}}
\DeclareNewFootnote{bl}[gobble]
\setlength{\skip\footinsbl}{0pt}

\begin{document}
Hi there! I'm using whatsapp!\footnotebl{Though not much ...}
\clearpage
Hi there! I'm using whatsapp!\footnotebl{Though not much ...}\footnote{normal footnote}
Text

Hi there! I'm using whatsapp!\footnote{normal footnote}\footnotebl{Second: Though not much ...}
Text 
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

Note that `mdframed` uses the syntax of environment `minipage` with the same counter. So the suggestion above will not work inside `mdframed`.

But if you want to use only the nonumbered and noindented footnotes in a `mdframed` environment you can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
  [startinnercode={\deffootnotemark{}\deffootnote{0pt}{0pt}{}}]
Hi there! I'm using whatsapp!\footnote{Though not much ...}
\end{mdframed}

Hi there! I'm using whatsapp!\footnote{normal footnote}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possible to combine both suggestions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\SetFootnoteHook{\hspace*{-1.8em}}
\DeclareNewFootnote{bl}[gobble]
\setlength{\skip\footinsbl}{0pt}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
  [startinnercode={\deffootnotemark{}\deffootnote{0pt}{0pt}{}}]
Hi there! I'm using whatsapp!\footnote{Though not much ...}
\end{mdframed}

Hi there! I'm using whatsapp!\footnotebl{Though not much ...}\footnote{normal footnote}

Hi there! I'm using whatsapp!\footnote{normal footnote}\footnotebl{Second: Though not much ...}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I really like your second approach (the one with just `scrextend`. However, instead of placing `[startinnercode={\deffootnotemark{}\deffootnote{0pt}{0pt}{}}]` in every box, I place it inside `\newmdtheoremenv[...]{...}{...}`, and then the effect is general. Though it's a minor issue, I thought it was best pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to behave mostly like a 'normal' footnote from the `article` class, then you should adapt the existing footnote commands. Here, `\@blfootnotetext` is identical to `\@footnotetext`, and `\@makeblfntext` is slightly modified from `\@makefntext`. Then we `\def` `\blfootnote` to use `\@blfootnotetext`....

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=2in]{geometry}% just for the example

\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@blfootnotetext}
% based on latex.ltx
\long\def\@blfootnotetext#1{\insert\footins{%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
    }%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makeblfntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}%
% based on article.cls
\newcommand\@makeblfntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@0em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hi there! I'm using whatsapp!\blfootnote{Though not much...}
Hi there! I'm using whatsapp!\footnote{Though not much...}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you help here (in short, if not i will delete this (off-topic) comment): Why something like`\makeatletter
\let\makefntextCopie\makefntext
\def\blfootnote{\def\@thefnmark{}\def\@makefntextCopie{\relax}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother` doesn't work? What do I wrong?

Comment: Suppose that this blfootnotes need to work inside mdframed boxes... What should I do, then? I ask it because your code works fine, but blfootnotes won't show up inside mdframed boxes.

Comment: @Héctor -- I never use `mdframed` so I don't know off-hand. Can you edit to add an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Bobyandbob -- As far as I know `\makefntext` is not defined, so you aren't actually `\let`ting anything. Also, you are defining `\blfootnote` to take zero arguments, so that will be a problem.

Comment: @jon -- You can see my edit now. Sorry I took so long.

Comment: @Héctor -- not a problem. Though I see you've already accepted an answer. Do you still want to see this solution adapted for `mdframed`?

Comment: @Jon  -- It's completely up to you, honestly. esdd solution worked fine and solved my issue, hence I accepted it. Still, not relying on external packages, as well as having alternative approaches to address an issue on the site, may be helpful not only to me but to others who may eventually reach this question.