# How to create a paragraph for the publisher information etc

Tags: journal-publishing

**I want to know if there is a name for this, and how to make one LaTeX.**

It's a paragraph, usually on the first page of a research paper, that provides information about the publisher and/or the author(s). It seems to be clearly distinct from adjacent text, perhaps it's even a float.

There is an example of what I mean at the first page of [this paper](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf), just above the footnote:

> Manuscript created February 25, 2002; revised August 26, 2015. This work
>   was supported by the IEEE. This work is distributed under the L
>   A
>   T
>   E
>   X Project
>   Public  License  (LPPL)  (  http://www.latex-project.org/  )  version  1.3.  A  copy
>   of the LPPL, version 1.3, is included in the base L
>   A
>   T
>   E
>   X documentation of all
>   distributions  of  L
>   A
>   T
>   E
>   X  released  2003/12/01  or  later.  The  opinions  expressed
>   here are entirely that of the author. No warranty is expressed or implied. User
>   assumes all risk

Sorry for being unclear, but I have no idea what search terms to use even.

Comment: It looks to me as you want a [footnote without a marker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30720/82917).

Comment: You might setup a page layout which includes this in the footline, using `scrlayer-scrpage` or `fancyhdr` or something similar.

Comment: Depending on your document class, which is is one of the reasons why you should always give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), you can redefine the effect of `\maketitle` with `\makeatother\def\@maketitle{...insert your title page specs here...}\makeatother`

Comment: i couldn't find anything useful in IEEEtran.cls, but \setbox\footins=\vbox{...} does the trick.  You can even put it in the preamble.