# Place Bibliography Item at Bottom of Frame Without a Citation

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing

I want a full citation to appear at the bottom of the beamer slide, but I don't want to have the a reference in the slide itself. I have tried to use `nocite` like this:

```
{\begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}
    \nocite{williams2000dynamic}
    \footfullcite{williams2000dynamic}
\end{minipage}}
```

and like this:

```
{\begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}
    \nocite{\footfullcite{williams2000dynamic}}
\end{minipage}}
```

The first leaves me with a reference on the minipage and the second with no citation at the bottom.
Is there any way to get the full citation in the bottom of the slide without having some reference to it in the slide body? or it least without having the reference appear visually on the slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the footnote without number from from [Footnote without a marker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30720/35864)

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\def\blx@blfootnote#1{\blfootnote{\protecting{\blxmkbibnote{foot}{#1}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcite}[\blx@blfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}[t]{1\linewidth}
  \blfootnote{\fullcite{sigfridsson}}
  \footfullcite{sigfridsson}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

`\nocite` just makes the entry appear in the bibliography at the end, it does not produce a citation. And the correct syntax is `\nocite{<entrykey>}` and not `\nocite{\cite{<entrykey>}}`.