# Float a the bottom of the text area (without \vfill)

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

I would like to add some information at the bottom of the text area. This information is automatically generated and inserted just after the `\maketitle` command such that I cannot use `\vfill`. So far, I've used a float placed at the bottom but I'm not sure this is the best solution and it doesn't work in every case because it depends on what follows.

My question is then what is the best way to do that ? Ideally, the solution should also work in two-columns. I've tried to adapt the [PNAS template](https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/pnas) but without much success.

Here is a minimal working example illustrating the problem (just comment/uncomment last few lines to see the difference in placement).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=4cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,float,tikz}

\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{statement}{b!}{sst}
\title{A Title}
\author{An author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{statement}
  \hrule \vskip .5em \sffamily \footnotesize
  This should appear at the bottom of the text area (whatever follows).
\end{statement}

\section{Section}
\lipsum*[1]\\

\begin{figure}[h]
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node[draw, fill=black!5, dashed, thick,
       text width=.98\textwidth, minimum height=6.8cm] at (0,0) {~~\sf Figure};
   \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption. }
\end{figure}

\lipsum*[2]\\

%% When commented, the float is at the right place (bottom of the text area)
%% When uncommented, the float is not at the right place
%% \section{Section}
%% \lipsum*[1-2]\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: You want a footnote without a number.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker

Comment: No, not a footnote, just a regular paragraph placed at then end of the text area (look a the blue box in the PNAS template). They're using afterpage + float but for some reason it does not work for me.

Comment: There’s no problem with the placement of `statement` if you’d replace `\lipsum*[2]` with a longer text `\lipsum*[1-2]` (please *do not* use manual line-break `\\ `). The “floating” issue is caused by the following section heading: Since there isn’t enough space to put the heading *and* a few line of text, TeX decides to push everything to the next page. But then there would be white space left on the first page, and TeX thinks leaving the space at the bottom of the page is *superior* to leaving it *within* body text, since the latter would interrupt the flow of reading.

Comment: I know, but I still want to place the statement at the bottom of the text area whatever TeX thinks is best.