# Footnote without a marker for moderncv documentclass

Tags: luatex, footnotes, moderncv, latexmk, texlive-2017

I have trouble getting the answer from [Footnote without a marker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker) to work for my `moderncv` document and TeX Live 2017, LuaLaTeX 1.0.4 and Latexmk 4.53a.

The following document:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\blfootnote{TEST}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with `latexmk` and following `latexmkrc` file:

```
$ENV{TEXINPUTS} = ".:../latex:" . ($ENV{TEXINPUTS} or "");

$recorder = 1;

# Use LuaTeX, supported since Latexmk 4.51
$pdf_mode = 4;
$dvi_mode = $postscript_mode = 0;

$bibtex_use = 2;

$lualatex = "lualatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S";
$pdflatex = "pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S";
```

Results in following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\H@@footnotetext ...color@begingroup \@makefntext 
                                                  {\rule \z@ \footnotesep \i...

l.11 \blfootnote{TEST}
```

How do I make this work with the `moderncv` documentclass?

Comment: I got unrelated errors due to missing definitions.  I checked the manual, except there isn't one (manual that is).  There are supposed to be examples, but I coudn't find them.

Comment: You might need to add `\name{Jon}{Doe}` to the preamble. Though I did not need that to produce the error I quoted.

Comment: Note that the `\blfootnote` command has a flaw: It does not insert the footnote mark, but it does insert a space and a hyperlink, just like regular footnotes have their anchor somewhere in the regular text. This might make it unsuitable to to use it to just display some text at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered on StackOverflow previously (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779686/using-footnotes-with-moderncv-class-in-latex): `moderncv` does not support footnotes.  It has to be added using the `footmisc` package:

```
\usepackage{footmisc} % Footnote support
```

Comment: For anyone trying to use `moderncv` with `\addbibresource`, THIS is the answer to all of your problems.  Thanks @devurandom !