# Footnote which is not a footnote

Tags: footnotes, typography, acknowledgements

I would like to write not more than two lines at the bottom of a page, in order to thank some people, without dedicating a whole acknowledgements section of my work to that. It would be nice to draw a kind of straight line at the top of these two lines. Hence, I'm talking about a sort of footnote, which is not a proper footnote, doesn't have the purpose of a footnote and of course is not numbered. I don't even know how I could refer to such a thing, and if this is standard.

How could I do that?

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30720 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

text{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{footnote that is not a footnote}}

text\footnote{normal footnote}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcommand\nfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \endgroup
}


\begin{document}

Text\footnote{One}

Text\nfootnote{Two}

Text\footnote{Three}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: Attrib - I see originally from [Footnote without a marker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/)