# Remove indent from specially defined footnote command

Tags: footnotes, indentation

Following the top answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker), I've created an unnumbered footnote for use in a document like so:

```
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \endgroup
\endgroup }
```

This removes the superscript number from both the main text and from the start of the footnote, but the start of the footnote is still indented. How can I change the newly defined command above so that the unnumbered footnote is not indented at the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 2):

I have slightly modified the code what you provided:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup%
\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{\hspace{-4pt}#1}%
\endgroup}%

\begin{document}

Some text\blfootnote{A footnote without marker} and some more text\footnote{A standard footnote}

Test

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem and you solved it thanks! But in my case I had to add a negative space of 22pt because my footnotes are in scriptsize. Is there a way to just specify no indent so it always work independently of character size or font? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The space used for the footnote number in the footnote is `1.8em`, stemming from the definition of `\@makefntext`. The following fixes your issue by removing the indent.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\blfootnote}{ m }{{%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\thefootnote}{}{\roman{footnote}}% roman{0} = empty
  \footnotetext[0]{\hspace*{-1.8em}#1}% Undo 1.8em indent
}}%

\begin{document}

Some text\blfootnote{A footnote without marker} and some more text\footnote{A standard footnote}

Test

\end{document}
```

Additionally, it sets the footnote number as `0`, which printed in `\roman` (only temporarily within `\blfootnote`; note the double braces/group) is empty.

Comment: It works thanks!