# footnote without mark but ordered

Tags: footnotes

[Footnote without a marker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker)

Using it can crete footnotes without marks but they will can be confusing with marked footnotes.

```
  note 1
  1 note 2
  note 3
```

note 3 can be seen as an extension of note 2.

I'm thinking that using a symbol will work to distinguish between the notes but adding it to the front produces an offset issue.

```
    ! note 1
  1 note 2
    ! note 3
```

What I'd like is a command where I can set the footnote symbol

```
\footnoteX[\dagger]{footnote1}
\footnoteX{footnote2}
\footnoteX[\dagger]{footnote3}
```

and it would replace the counter with dagger, all the alignment will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hacking together some stuff gives

```
\usepackage[perpage, para*]{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{Anonymous}
\DeclareNewFootnote{Main}
\MakePerPage{Main}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fn}[2][\@nil]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\tmp{#1}%  
  \ifx\tmp\@nnil
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}\noindent\footnoteMain{#2}%
  \else
    \ifx\tmp\empty
        \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\FootnotetextAnonymous{\dagger}{#2}%    
    \else
        \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\FootnotetextAnonymous{#1}{#2}%    
    \fi
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

and seems to work.

```
\fn{}   [uses counter]
\fn[]{} [default to dagger]
\fn[*]{} [uses * as symbol]
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not match exactly what you want because it groups the different kinds of footnotes rather than interspersing them, but I post in case it is useful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\fnsymbol{footnoteB}}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text.\footnote{A footnote.}
Filler text.\footnote{Another footnote.}
Filler text.\footnoteB{Yet another footnote.}
Filler text.\footnote{Still yet another footnote.}
Filler text.\footnoteB{How many footnotes can you get?}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: I'd rather not use multiple commands... see my answer for a solution that seems to work. It does not order them, which would only be the last thing I'd want, but otherwise it does everything else. Maybe it can be modified to use what you have done? (Declare a new footnote and use that) Also, I'd like to stick the symbols at the front rather than below.

Comment: You can put the symbols as the first group. To me there isn't much difference in using a different command to using an optional argument. It seems like `bigfoot` can intersperse, but I can't make sense of the manual at the moment.

Comment: I was able to use many foot to get what I wanted using your method. The only problem is that I would like to left-justify the footnote and indent any wrapped lines rather than the reverse. When I use para it puts footnotes on the same line. It's not a huge deal but that would be the last thing I'd want.

Comment: @Chieron, I think `manyfoot` can work with `footmisc` to format your footnotes how you want.