# How can I add two "different sets" of footnotes on LaTeX?

Tags: footnotes, footer

[image]

I'm writing a commemorative article and I want the first footnote to mention that it is dedicated to someone. I've already figured out how to add a footnote without numbering. But I would also like that the dedicatory be enclosed by an upper and lower line apart from the other footnotes (Something like the example from the picture). How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us what have you tried? Also your question is not very clear, can you post an image illustrating what you want to achieve?

Comment: I edited my question and added an image. Thanks @Niranjan

Comment: @DiogoDias In the question you mention that you already tried a solution to this yourself. Could you please add some code to the question as well, just something short that shows what you've tried and that other people can compile too (a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/172164)). That way it is much easier to help you, for example at the moment it's not known what documentclass or packages you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Package `manyfoot.sty` may suits with your requirement, the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{manyfoot}

\newfootnote{A}
\newfootnote{B}
\newcounter{footnoteA}
\newcommand{\footnoteA}{%
   \stepcounter{footnoteA}%
   \Footnotemark\thefootnoteA \FootnotetextA{}}
\newcounter{footnoteB}
\newcommand{\footnoteB}{%
   \stepcounter{footnoteB}%
   \Footnotemark\thefootnoteB \FootnotetextB\thefootnoteB}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\roman{footnoteB}}

\begin{document}

Blah\footnoteA{This is for test}

Blah\footnoteB{This is for test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\blfootnote{Dedicated to bla bla bla\smallskip\footnoterule}\blfootnote{This paper constitutes XYZ\bigskip}\blfootnote{Springer Publication}
\end{document}
```

Is this what you want?

[image]

PS - The code for `blfootnote` is obtained from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker) answer.