# Add a Footnote without Marker and Link in IEEEtran

Tags: footnotes, ieeetran, ieee-style, author, ieeeconf

I want to add a footnote without marker and internal link to the footnote for a author in IEEEtran. How can I do this?
[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker) approach is good but it create an empty link in text.