# Footnote without a marker AND no space

Tags: footnotes

I'm using the solution provided in [Footnote without a marker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker). The MWE from that solution is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Some text\blfootnote{A footnote without marker} and some more text\footnote{A standard 
footnote}

\end{document}
```

The result of this MWE is:
[image]
As you can see, the letter A is vertically aligned in both the blind footnote and the normal footnote. This is because there is a space to the left of the footnote. How do I get rid of that space? (I'm using a two-column page layout, so my "footnotes" appear on the side of the page, the text is left justified, so the space looks weird)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
% footnoteprob.tex  SE 590907

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{\noindent\makebox[1.8em][r]#1}
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text\blfootnote{A footnote without marker} and some more text\footnote{A standard 
footnote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way I think that the result you are after looks odd.