# How to add copyright information at the bottom of chapter page?

Tags: copyright, bottom, chapter-page

How to add copyright information at the bottom of the first page of Chapter 1 as follows (if possible we can add the copyright information at another, note necessarily all, chapter page)?

[image]

The following is an MWE. Thanks very much!

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Fruit}
\section{Apple}
Some texts\footnote{Blind texts.}
\section{Pear}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done along these lines:

```
% chapcopyrightprob.tex  SE 650600

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}{%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyfoot[L]{\footnotesize\copyright{} Text of the copyright\\ on a couple of lines}%
\fancyfoot[R]{\small\thepage}%
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}%
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\chapter{First}
%\thispagestyle{crchap}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1]

More text.\footnote{George Boole}

\newpage

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since we may have already defined or used a `fancy` page style, we could define a `copyright` page style instead as follows.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{copyright}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\footnotesize\copyright{} Text of the copyright\\ on a couple of lines}%
\fancyfoot[R]{\small\thepage}%
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}%
}
```

---

It is a pity that your MWE shows nothing to do with your problem. -- GOM

Comment: I improved the codes and gave some more statements.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly changed solution from [Footnote without a marker AND no space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/590907/footnote-without-a-marker-and-no-space) so I am not taking credits for the answer.

However, I think in that case `makebox` is unnecessary. Also, if the copyright statement is meant to be visually separated from the other footnotes, I'd add `\rule{0pt}{<v-len>}` to add an extra vertical space above the statement

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
    \urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\blfootnote{s O{12pt} m}{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{\noindent \IfBooleanT{#1}{\rule{0pt}{#2}}#3}
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]

Some text\footnote{Sample}

Some text\footnote{Sample}

Some text\footnote{Sample}

\blfootnote*{\copyright{} The author(s), under exclusive license to Springer ... \kant*[2][1-2] \url{https://doi.org/...}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not exactly, since it's over the page numbers, and I don't know why `12pt` has no effect in the book documentclass. Anyway, thanks very much.

Answer (score -1):

I get an answer involving the `tikz` package by improving the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55815/140814). Note that

1. you should compile the file twice;
2. the `yshift` value is determined by you completely;
3. the `xshift` value is determined by you partially and also influenced by the left and right margins, for example, if the left and right margins are x cm and y cm respectively, then the `xshift` value should be -(x-y)/2 cm (if you also want the copyright information and texts above it to be aligned left). I don't know how to avoid such calculation.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[papersize={15.6cm,23.4cm},
top=2cm,bottom=3cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\copyrighttext}{\footnotesize%
\textcopyright{} The Author(s), under exclusive license to Springer Nature Switzerland AG 2021
\\ H.-D. Ebbinghaus et al., \emph{Mathematical Logic}, Graduate Texts in Mathematics 291,
\\ \url{https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-73839-6_1}
}
\newcommand{\copyrightnotice}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[xshift=0cm,yshift=1.8cm] at (current page.south) {\parbox{\textwidth}{\copyrighttext}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\copyrightnotice
\footnote{Blind texts}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]