# Disable hyperref link for single footnote

Tags: hyperref, footnotes

I have used [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30726/114945) to create a footnote without a marker. As answered, it works fine. However, if you include the hyprref package, the package creates an content-less link for the marker-less footnote:

[image]

I could disable the footnote links, e.g.

```
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
```

but I would prefer if the other footnotes in the document did have links. Is there a way to disable the footnote link for a single footnote?

#### MVE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

Some text\blfootnote{A footnote without marker} and some more text\footnote{A standard footnote}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the NoHyper environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begin{NoHyper}%
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \end{NoHyper}%
}

\begin{document}

Some text\blfootnote{A footnote without marker} and some more text\footnote{A standard footnote}

\end{document}
```