# Disable references in pgfplot legends

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I would like to display a common legend for a `groupplot` like this:

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
      {group size=1 by 1}},
    legend entries={A, B},
    legend columns=2,
    legend to name=grouplegend]

    \nextgroupplot[title=One]
    \addplot+[color=Blue] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
    \addplot+[color=Red] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
  \end{groupplot}

  \node (l1) at ($(group c1r1.south)$)
  [below, yshift=-2\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/every axis title shift}]
  {\ref{grouplegend}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As seen in the result, the legend contains a reference to the figure (hyperref of course producing a box around it). Is there a way to disable this reference?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With this post [Disable hyperref link for single footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593640/disable-hyperref-link-for-single-footnote/593645#593645), I tried this:

```
\newcommand\blref[1]{%
  \begin{NoHyper}%
    \ref{#1}
  \end{NoHyper}%
}
```

The complet code

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}%<-- added
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{}
\newcommand\blref[1]{%
  \begin{NoHyper}%
    \ref{#1}
  \end{NoHyper}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
      {group size=1 by 1}},
    legend entries={A, B},
    legend columns=2,
    legend to name=grouplegend]

    \nextgroupplot[title=One]
    \addplot+[color=Blue] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
    \addplot+[color=Red] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
  \end{groupplot}

  \node (l1) at ($(group c1r1.south)$)
  [below, yshift=-2\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/every axis title shift}]
  {\blref{grouplegend}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, If I have a larger grid of say 3x3 groups, I would like to place the legend at a specified position outside of the grid, which is greatly helped based on the `legend to name` tool. For a single plot I would indeed use the basic approach instead.

Comment: A new answer, maybe this is what you wanted.