# Error with hyperref + tabular + footnotes in tabular

Tags: tables, hyperref, footnotes

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\fntxt}[1]{\footnotetext{#1}}
\newcommand{\fnstep}{\stepcounter{footnote}}
\newcommand{\fnmark}{\footnotemark}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
\hline
Test1\fnmark & Test2\fnmark \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\fntxt{Footnote 1}
\fnstep
\fntxt{Footnote 2}

\end{document}
```

I `pdflatex` it twice. The problem is: (1) when I click on the first footnote, I'm "transferred" to the same page, not pointed to the first footnote text; (2) when I click on the second, I'm correctly pointed to the second footnote text.

I've also tried to add more than two footnotes in the tabular. It turns out that only the last reference is working.

What's the reason behind this? How can one fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

The `hyperref` support for footnotes can be easily broken; here's what the `hyperref` documentation says about the `hyperfootnotes` option:

```
Makes the footnote marks into hyperlinks to the footnote text. Easily broken...
```

In [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/73be4ac1dd828176/c4d1f8e0a8e7bf76?lnk=gst&q=%5Cfootnotemark%20hyperref#c4d1f8e0a8e7bf76) at *comp.text.tex*, Heiko Oberdiek says (referring to the same issue discussed here):

> It is beyond the scope of `hyperref`'s footnote support.  Thus you can
>   either disable it: `hyperfootnotes=false`  or you have to fiddle with
>   internal macros.

And here's the fiddling he announces (and illustrates with an exampe) adapted to your particular situation:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter 
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Test1\footnotemark 
  \global\let\saved@Href@A\Hy@footnote@currentHref 
&
Test2\footnotemark 
  \global\let\saved@Href@B\Hy@footnote@currentHref 
\end{tabular}

\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}% 
\let\Hy@footnote@currentHref\saved@Href@A 
\footnotetext{Footnote text}% 
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}% 
\let\Hy@footnote@currentHref\saved@Href@B 
\footnotetext{Footnote text}% 

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please place `Text\footnote{Footnote one}` before `\makeatletter`. The table will float to the top of the page, 
but the footnote numbers will not be adapted. (The `tablefootnote` package used in my answer has got the same problem.)
Any idea how to solve that? (Except moving the table in the source code before the `Text\footnote{Footnote one}` or preventing the floating.)

Comment: @gonzalo-medina is it possible to develop this idea in a new package? This would make easier its use and we can use it in others environments as `minipages` or `\fbox{...}`. I say this because you are an expert in (La)TeX programming.

Answer (score 1):

If it is OK for you to use the tabular inside of a table environment, you could use the [tablefootnote](http://ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote) package and just use `\tablefootnote{ ... }` in the table. (And optionally you can center the table and add a caption.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
%\centering
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
\hline
Test1\tablefootnote{Footnote 1} & Test2\tablefootnote{Footnote 2} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
%\caption{This is a table.\label{FirstTable}}
\end{table}

A pagebreak:

\pagebreak

and a second page, so that you can see that the hyperlinks really work.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I decided to give it a try and I followed the README document to manually install the package. However, even after `initexmf --update-fndb`, neither `pdflatex` nor `latex` could compile. I'm using MikTex. Have any ideas?

Comment: @Covi: Please see at 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35200/footnotes-in-tabulars/35327#35327