# Making global footnotes inside a minipage with hyperref support

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, counters, minipage

I would like to make footnotes inside a minipage that use the global footnote counters and the hyperref package.

I'm having trouble getting hyperref to make the correct references. I imagine I need to change the Hfootnote counter but I haven't had any luck with that and I'm not sure exactly what's going on. I tried adding a \addtocounter{Hfootnote}{-1} and \stepcounter{Hfootnote} but that didn't help.

Below is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\noindent\ldots{} main text\footnote{Before minipage} \ldots\par
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    A footnote to use global footnotes.\footnotemark
    A second global footnote.\footnotemark
\end{minipage}}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\footnotetext{First global footnote inside minipage}
\stepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext{Second global footnote inside minipage}
\par
\noindent\ldots{} main text\footnote{After minipage} \ldots\par
\end{document}
```

Clicking on the first footnote inside the minipage does not yeild the expected result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured it out! The short answer is that Hyperref sucks at footnotes.

Thanks to [Gonzalo Medina's answer to a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35298/error-with-hyperref-tabular-footnotes-in-tabular?rq=1) I was able to adapt a workaround. I'm new to tex.stackechange so if I can give any more credit to Medina please let me know how.

Below is the working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\noindent\ldots{} main text\footnote{Before minipage} \ldots\par
\makeatletter
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    A footnote to use global footnotes.\footnotemark\global\let\saved@Href@A\Hy@footnote@currentHref
    A second global footnote.\footnotemark\global\let\saved@Href@B\Hy@footnote@currentHref
\end{minipage}}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\let\Hy@footnote@currentHref\saved@Href@A 
\footnotetext{First global footnote inside minipage}
\stepcounter{footnote}
\let\Hy@footnote@currentHref\saved@Href@B
\footnotetext{Second global footnote inside minipage}
\makeatother
\par
\noindent\ldots{} main text\footnote{After minipage} \ldots\par 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This response seems a bit cryptic. Is there a package that makes this easier?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The linked answer provides a better explanation, but the short answer is hyperref wasn't designed to work on footnotes.

Comment: i tried `tablefootnote` but it works only into a `table` (or `sidewaystable`) environment and no in `minipage` or `\fbox{}`.

Comment: The above example works with `minipage`. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, perhaps you should open your own question, then I would be glad to help if I can.

Comment: Adding comments using `%` symbols to your MWE would have helped to make this answer a whole lot less cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a cleaner solution for this, but I had to use `mdframed` instead of `fbox` + `minipage`, as `fbox` makes the footnotes disappear for some reason.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{footnotehyper}
% Make mdframed pushes all footnotes to the end of the page
\makesavenoteenv{mdframed}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% Fix \footnotetext inside boxes causing numbers to disappear at the end of the page
\let\thempfootnote\thefootnote

\begin{document}
\noindent\ldots{} main text\footnote{Before minipage} \ldots\par

\begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=0.5\linewidth]
A footnote to use global footnotes.\footnotemark
\footnotetext{First global footnote inside minipage}
A second global footnote.\footnotemark
\footnotetext{Second global footnote inside minipage}
\end{mdframed}

\par
\noindent\ldots{} main text\footnote{After minipage} \ldots\par
\end{document}
```