# Multiple footnotes within a mdframed to refer to the same text

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, mdframed, links

I am using an `mdframed` to a display large list of items. In this this list, there is *one* exception that a few of the items have, and I am trying to make a note of this via a footnote. The text of the footnote is the same for *all* the exceptions. So what I would like is:

- Multiple footnotes using the same symbol (in each mdframed)
- Each of the footnotes to link to the *one* piece of text at the end of *each* mdframed

I tried the *hack* below based on [Making global footnotes inside a minipage with hyperref support](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119092/making-global-footnotes-inside-a-minipage-with-hyperref-support), which gets me the same symbol for the footnote, but only the last footnote is properly linked.

### Notes:

- If at all possible I would prefer to *not* have to do multiple runs.  Since one instant of the footnote does not require multiple runs I think  this should be doable without that.

### References:

- [Changing footnote symbol within mdframed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175951/changing-footnote-symbol-within-mdframed)
- [Making global footnotes inside a minipage with hyperref support](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119092/making-global-footnotes-inside-a-minipage-with-hyperref-support)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
%% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119092/making-global-footnotes-inside-a-minipage-with-hyperref-support
\newcommand*{\MyFootnoteMark}{%
    \footnotemark%
%   \global\let\saved@Href@A\Hy@footnote@currentHref%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
}%

\newcommand*{\MyFootnoteText}[1]{%
%%  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
%   \let\Hy@footnote@currentHref\saved@Href@A%
    \footnotetext{#1}%
    \stepcounter{footnote}%
}%
\makeatother


%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175951/changing-footnote-symbol-within-mdframed
\makeatletter
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or
   \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger
   \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}%
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}   
\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\MyContent}[1][yellow!20]{%
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=#1]
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\color{blue}
Hey, look at me.\MyFootnoteMark
\end{minipage}%
\par\lipsum[2]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\color{blue}
Hey, look at me\MyFootnoteMark again.\par
\end{minipage}%
\par\lipsum[3-6]
\MyFootnoteText{This is the text that all the footnotes refers to.}
\end{mdframed}%
}%


\begin{document}
\MyContent[yellow!20]

\MyContent[green!20]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I don't really know what I am doing! I should be sleeping!</sub>

Add `\addtocounter{Hfootnote}{-1}%` additionally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
%% Adapted from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119092/making-global-footnotes-inside-a-minipage-with-hyperref-support
\newcommand*{\MyFootnoteMark}{%
    \footnotemark%
%   \global\let\saved@Href@A\Hy@footnote@currentHref%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \addtocounter{Hfootnote}{-1}%     Added
}%

\newcommand*{\MyFootnoteText}[1]{%
%%  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
%   \let\Hy@footnote@currentHref\saved@Href@A%
    \footnotetext{#1}%
    \stepcounter{footnote}%
    \stepcounter{Hfootnote}%      %% Added
}%
\makeatother


%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175951/changing-footnote-symbol-within-mdframed
\makeatletter
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or
   \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger
   \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}%
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\MyContent}[1][yellow!20]{%
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=#1]
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\color{blue}
Hey, look at me.\MyFootnoteMark
\end{minipage}%
\par\lipsum[2]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\color{blue}
Hey, look at me\MyFootnoteMark again.\par
\end{minipage}%
\par\lipsum[3-6]
\MyFootnoteText{This is the text that all the footnotes refers to.}
\end{mdframed}%
}%


\begin{document}
\MyContent[yellow!20]

\MyContent[green!20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another ugly hack to bring back the symbols in the footnote

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed,footnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
%% Adapted from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119092/making-global-footnotes-inside-a-minipage-with-hyperref-support
\newcommand*{\MyFootnoteMark}{%
    \footnotemark%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \addtocounter{Hfootnote}{-1}%     Added
}%

\newcommand{\MyFootnoteText}[1]{%
    \footnotetext[\numexpr\value{footnote}+1\relax]{#1}%
    \refstepcounter{footnote}%
    \refstepcounter{Hfootnote}%      %% Added
}%
\makeatother


%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175951/changing-footnote-symbol-within-mdframed
\makeatletter
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or
   \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger
   \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}%
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyContent}{O{yellow!20}O{}}{%
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=#1]
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\color{blue}
Hey, look at me.\MyFootnoteMark
\end{minipage}%
\par\lipsum[2]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\color{blue}
Hey, look at me\MyFootnoteMark again.\par
\end{minipage}%
\par\lipsum[3-6]
\MyFootnoteText{This is the text that all the footnotes refers to.}
\end{mdframed}%
}%


\begin{document}
\MyContent[yellow!20]

\MyContent[green!20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This _almost_ works. The links for the yellow `mdframed` are correct. But the links for the green `mdframed` block link back to the footnote in the yellow block.

Comment: Harish, just noticed that the footnote marks are not showing up in the footnotes itself. Only the text shows up.  Any ideas as to why? Otherwise it seems to work great.

Comment: @PeterGrill Added another ugly hack!.