# Footnotes not showing up (no tables involved here!)

Tags: footnotes

I'm having a difficult time with footnotes because I'm trying to do a project report and some footnotes do show up, other don't. Here is a minimal document showing this behavior:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

Working footnote\footnote{Footnote is present!}

\begin{description}

\item[Entrée vidéo ASI]
\emph{Asynchronous Serial Interface}~: interface de transmission très
similaire au SDI~: en effet, les mêmes composants sont utilisés. La
principale différence est que les données sont déjà compressées et
habituellement encapsulées dans un flux MPEG-TS\footnote{This footnote
shows up, perfect.}.

\item[Memoires DDR2\footnote{This note has disappeared!} SDRAM\footnote{So as this one!}] Ces mémoires volatiles perdent
leurs informations lorsqu'elles ne sont plus alimentées ni rafraîchies !

\item[Entrée vidéo ASI bis]
\emph{Asynchronous Serial Interface}~: interface de transmission très
similaire au SDI~: en effet, les mêmes composants sont utilisés. La
principale différence est que les données sont déjà compressées et
habituellement encapsulées dans un flux MPEG-TS\footnote{Again, this
one works perfectly!}.

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

I feel like I've tried everything but with no luck!

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and the problem shows up with pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX, whether I use the command line or TeXworks.

Answer (score 5):

The phenomenon of disappearing footnotes is the same as for tables and the solution is the same:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\setlength{\textheight}{8cm}% just for the example

\begin{document}

Working footnote\footnote{Footnote is present!}

\begin{description}

\item[Entrée vidéo ASI]
\emph{Asynchronous Serial Interface} : interface de transmission très
similaire au SDI : en effet, les mêmes composants sont utilisés. La
principale différence est que les données sont déjà compressées et
habituellement encapsulées dans un flux MPEG-TS\footnote{This footnote
shows up, perfect.}.

\item[Memoires DDR2\footnotemark\ SDRAM\footnotemark]%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \footnotetext{This note has not disappeared!}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{1}%
  \footnotetext{So as this one!}% 
Ces mémoires volatiles perdent leurs informations lorsqu'elles ne sont plus alimentées ni rafraîchies !

\item[Entrée vidéo ASI bis]
\emph{Asynchronous Serial Interface} : interface de transmission très
similaire au SDI : en effet, les mêmes composants sont utilisés. La
principale différence est que les données sont déjà compressées et
habituellement encapsulées dans un flux MPEG-TS\footnote{Again, this
one works perfectly!}.

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

If only one footnote is in the optional argument to `\item`, then no `\addtocounter` instruction is needed.

[image]

As an aside, note that, if you use `babel-french` you don't have to type `~:` for the colons.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I'm using babel-french for hyphenation, but I don't write the TeX code myself, I process a Markdown input converted using Pandoc, so if there is a more automatic answer, it would be great.

Comment: is it possible that your answer is compatible with the `hyperref` package?

Comment: @skpblack See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35304/4427

Comment: @Ploppe I'm afraid there's no better method, lest of avoiding footnotes in the argument of `\item`.

Comment: @egreg thanks to @GonzaloMedina the hack works perfectly here and is compatible with `hyperref`.