# Classicthesis: how to get "unlinked" footnotes?

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, classicthesis

In a document using the `classicalthesis` package, in order to get footnotes without links (*) (but leave the links everywhere else), I tried all the options I could find: using  `\hypersetup` with `hyperfootnotes=false`, loading `hyperref` again (it is loaded automatically by `classicalthesis`) with the same option (**), changing the order of the loads in all possible ways, ... nothing worked: the darn footnotes were still links.

I tried to generate a MEW, but to no avail: the *only* way to get linkless footnotes was to comment out the line using the package. So I looked at classicalthesis' source code, and modified it by adding `[hyperfootnotes=false]` on the two places where `hyperref` is loaded:

```
    % ********************************************************************                
    % PDF and XeLaTeX Stuff
    % ********************************************************************
    \RequirePackage{ifpdf}
    \ifpdf\RequirePackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}\fi % for texorpdfstring command below

    % Necessary to rewrite hacks for chapters and parts and toc
    \RequirePackage{ifxetex}
    \ifxetex\RequirePackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}\fi % for texorpdfstring command below

    % pdfspacing does not work with XeLaTeX
    \ifxetex%
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{@pdfspacing}}%
                {% pdfspacing is used with XeLaTeX
                        \PackageWarningNoLine{classicthesis}{You cannot use the option %
                        "pdfspacing" with XeLaTeX!}%
                }{\relax}%
        \setboolean{@pdfspacing}{false}%
    \fi
```

This did the trick! But my question is: is there a simpler way? Preferably one that does *not* involve modifying any package's source code?

(*) - The reason I wanted this in the first place was because the links of the footnotes were wrong, and when trying to correct them, I [discovered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35298/error-with-hyperref-tabular-footnotes-in-tabular) that even hyperref's developer admitted that the linked footnotes were a brittle functionality... So I gave it up altogether.

(**) - This threw an error complaining the hyperref was being (re)loaded with incompatible options...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the option to the package.

[image: wmnorthClassicthesisHyperfootnote]

```
\documentclass[headinclude=true,footinclude=true]{scrreprt}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes=false}{hyperref}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\setlength{\textheight}{3cm}
\begin{document}
Pogo penguin\footnote{this is not a lazy leguan}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had actually tried adding that very line, but I had added it *after* the \usepackage... With hindsight, it's pretty darn obvious that it had to go before... thanks for pointing it out!