# numbering for a "dummy" footnote

Tags: footnotes

I have a number of footnotes in my document, but because of the nature of one of my tables, i can't get the footnote to appear on the same page as the table (i cant reproduce a self contained example of this without pasting my whole document, sorry)

So as a workaround, I have done this:
In my text i have:

```
this is some text that needs a footnote$^3$
```

and then added a couple of lines at the bottom of my table that go:

```
\hfill\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-4}
\multicolumn{10}{l}{$^3$\footnotesize{this is the footnote text.}}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

which produces the desired effect. My problem is, that if I insert another footnote in, then it will ruin my numbering.

is there some sort of `\footnotecounter` or something that i can use to change my line above to:

```
this is some text that needs a footnote$^\footnotecounter$
```

and then after my "dummy" footnote, increment this counter by one so subsequent footnotes will start at 4?

Comment: You can access the footnote counter using `\thefootnote`. To change numbering you can use: `\stepcounter{footnote}` or `\addtocounter{footnote}{2}`.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35200/footnotes-in-tabulars

Comment: So the footnote appears at the bottom of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Footnotes in tables are possible with packages or use `\footnotemark` toprepare a mark for a footnote and display the footnote after the table with `\footnotetext`.

However, the counter might need to have incremented manually if there are more footnotes` in the same table etc.

Please be aware, that floating tables will display 'wrong' footnote' numbers due to the place where the table is typeset and the `\footnotemark` is done finally.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

Some text\footnote{Another footnote}

%\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{*{10}l}
\hfill\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-4}
\multicolumn{10}{l}{Foo Foo\footnotemark} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{table}

\footnotetext{This is the footnote text.}
Another text with a footnote\footnote{Foobar}


\end{document}
```