# Putting footnotes on same page as table that references them

Tags: tables, footnotes, tabularx

I've got a `\tabularx` with two `\footnote` marks immediately followed by two `\footnotetext`.  I would like them to show up on the same page, but tex is pushing the table to the following page making relating the footnotes to the table difficult.  I tried `\samepage,` but that doesn't seem to keep them together.  Thoughts?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. Also, please, check if this question: [Footnotes in tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1583/footnotes-in-tables?rq=1) helps

Comment: LaTeX really wants you to use  a style such that the footnote text comes at the bottom of the table  rather than the bottom of the page.  The easiest way to get that is to put a minipage around the tabularx (but inside the floating table environment)  to get the footnote text on the page of a float would require some serious hacking of the output routine.

Comment: @user19274 (may i call you "74"?): [TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=footintab) covers all the options i know; fwiw, i prefer threeparttable...

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you try the package [tablefootnote](https://ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote). According to its documentation, it solves several problems with tables and footnotes, and integrates table footnotes with the footnotes in the the body text. From the example provided in the documentation, it handles footnotes in floating tables. Important for you: The documentation describes procedures for handling several ‘border cases’.

Comment: The URL is out of date, use http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote instead.

Comment: @Tombart Thank you. I have updated the link in the answer.

Comment: tablefootnote does not solve the issue of the footnote being placed on the wrong page. I also don't find the words in b"border" or "cases" in the linked documentation.