# References at the end of beamer slides

Tags: beamer, bibtex

I am preparing presentation with `beamer` and using `pdflatex` and `bibtex`. How can I put references at the end of a frame? What if I use allowframebreaks ?

I do not want all the references put together in one big frame at the end of my presentation, rather I want each reference as footnote on the frame where it has been used.

Note: I am using a custom bibliography style and author-year citation style.

MWE

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, 10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,mathtools}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{chngcntr}


\counterwithin*{footnote}{page}
\newcommand\footcite[1]{\footnote{\bibentry{#1}}\label{\thepage:#1}}
\newcommand\secondcite[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{\thepage:#1}}}



\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\definecolor{byublue}{RGB}{0 34 85}%added
\definecolor{mydarkgray}{RGB}{64 64 64}%added

\usecolortheme[named=MidnightBlue]{structure}%added
\usetheme{Montpellier}%Montpellier originally
\useoutertheme{tree}%added
\useinnertheme{circles}%added
\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}




\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif


\begin{document}
\nobibliography{bibliography_phd_journal_key}

\section{Introduction} 


\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
Some text \footcite{titanath2008p165326}
another test \secondcite{titanath2008p165326}
\end{center}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
Header\footcite{titanath2008p165326} & header \\ 
\hline 
1 & 2 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{frame} 


\bibliographystyle{mybibstyle}


\end{document}
```

I am using two external .bib files. One is the main .bib file and the other one is for journal name abbreviation.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: If this is the code you're using, there are a few problems. First, you have a \ in front of your bibfile name in the `\nobibliography` command.  Second, that command is just like a `\bibliography` command, and should simply contain the names of both your `.bib` files. Lastly, you need to remove the `\bibliography` command, it's not needed in this case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using `natbib` for references, then you can use the `bibentry` package to create references in footnotes.  It should be noted that this is a bit of a hack, and it doesn't really implement a proper footnote reference style, but emulates one.  To deal with subsequent citations (as you request in the comments) I've created a second command `\secondcite` which will place a footnote referencing the correct citation's original footnote number without duplicating the bibliography entry itself.   Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Saussure1995,
    Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
    Origyear = {1916},
    Publisher = {Payot},
    Title = {Cours de Linguistique G{\'e}n{\'e}rale},
    Year = {1995}}

@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

\end{filecontents}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin*{footnote}{page}
\newcommand\footcite[1]{\footnote{\bibentry{#1}}\label{\thepage:#1}}
\newcommand\secondcite[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{\thepage:#1}}}

\begin{document}
\nobibliography{\jobname}
\begin{frame}

  \frametitle{Stuff famous linguists asked}
  \begin{block}{A block}
       \begin{enumerate}
        \item Is it part of \emph{langue} or part of \emph{parole}?\footcite{Saussure1995}
        \item Is it socially stratified?\footcite{Labov1972}
        \item More Saussure\secondcite{Saussure1995}
       \end{enumerate}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
% The next frame is a duplicate for testing purposes    
\begin{frame}

  \frametitle{Stuff famous linguists asked}
  \begin{block}{A block}
       \begin{enumerate}
        \item Is it part of \emph{langue} or part of \emph{parole}?\footcite{Saussure1995}
        \item Is it socially stratified?\footcite{Labov1972}
        \item More Saussure\secondcite{Saussure1995}
       \end{enumerate}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

If  you want the references to be one big frame, then using `[allowframebreaks]` is the way to go.  I find the standard formatting of references in `beamer` overly garish, so I subdue everything:

```
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry author}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry location}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry note}{fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
```

I also allow for the "(cont.)" to be used on subsequent slides:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second]
```

The references slide itself is simple.

```
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\bibliography{<bibfile>}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Since usually you want the references to be one big frame', I do not want all the references put together in one big frame at the end of my presentation, rather I want the reference as footnote on the frame where it was used.

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question. What are you using for your bibliography - `natbib` or `biblatex`?  This is a lot easier to do with `biblatex`.

Comment: Yes I use `natbib' and I am not familiar with `biblatex'.

Comment: I am using `Montpellier' theme and this solution is not working in this theme.

Comment: How would I know what theme you are using? Also, if you substitute `Montpellier` in the sample document I gave, it still works. This is why you were asked to give an minimal example of your problem.

Comment: Yes, your MWE is working in Montpellier template. I am using two external .bib files and at present I do not know how to adapt those two in your code.

Comment: Using \footcite{bibkey} multiple times on same frame creating duplicates of same reference. How to stop that ?

Comment: There's no simple way to do this: what I've implemented here is not a true footnote citation system, it's a hack.  But I've added a new command to refer to an already cited reference on the same slide.

Comment: This works when used in text body but this is not working in table header. It is not reproducing the bibliography entry but the superscript number is not correct. I am modifying my MWE. Can it be solved ?

Comment: Footnotes in tables are *always* problematic. See [Footnotes in tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1583). This is a separate issue and should be asked as a separate question.   Given that this solution isn't the ideal way to do this, I would just avoid using it in a table.