# Biblatex: footnote citations. Two references to footnote in same slide

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I'm putting references at the bottom of Beamer slides. I'm referring to the same footnote twice in one slide, but latex is create a duplicate footnote: the label/ref is not working.

I found a version of this problem for natbib: [References at the end of beamer slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147279/references-at-the-end-of-beamer-slides)
However, I'm doing this in Biblatex as I need to format the citations.

How can I refer to the same footnote twice, but avoid having a duplicate footnote created? I need the counter to reset for each slide and start from 1 every frame. How can I reset the counter for every slide?

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},xcolor=x11names,compress,professionalfonts]{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citejournal}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{journal}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\tiny}
\newcommand{\customcite}[1]{(\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1})}
\newcommand{\customfootcite}[1]{\footnote{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1}), \emph{\citetitle{#1}.} \citejournal{#1}}}

%\newcommand\foootcite[1]{\footnote{\tiny\bibentry{#1}}\label{\thepage:#1}}
%\newcommand\secondcite[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{\thepage:#1}}}%This worked in Natbib, but is commented out because I'm using Biblatex now. . .

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} %Removes quotiation marks, puts italics
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1} % italic journal title with comma
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\hspace{-2pt}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{pages}\clearfield{volume}}

\include{formatting}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Motivation}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Individual investor behaviour: Household finance
    \item Rationality in individual preference models vs behavioural finance
    \item Rational learning vs biased learning~\customcite{murray}~\customfootcite{murray}
    \item Learning by doing vs learning about ability~\customfootcite{murray}
    \item Experimental studies: immediate outcomes~\customfootcite{augustine} \& well-structured feedback~\customfootcite{cotton}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As defined, your `\customfootcite` command has no way of knowing anything other than that it should print the information you've told it to.  If this is a one-time thing, I'd recommend simply using `\footnote[<num>]`, where `<num>` is the number corresponding to to the footnote number that is created for the first use of `\customfootcite{murray}`.  Otherwise you are going to need to invest time creating a more robust citation style for.

Comment: Is it possible, at least, to restart the counter for `\customfootcite` on each slide?

Comment: My guess would be yes if you do: `\usepackage{perpage}` and `\MakePerPage{footnote}`; or `\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}`.  But I have never used either with `beamer`...

Comment: BTW: [When should I use \input vs. \include?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/16967)

Comment: @jon \usepackage{perpage}  \MakePerPage{footnote} works great in beamer. Thanks. Consider extending that an answer so I can upvote it? \usepackage[perpage]{footmisc} does not work in combination with biblatex and beamer, though idk what breaks it.