# References at the end of beamer slides (Endnote export as text file)

Tags: beamer, bibtex

I'm having difficulties making a footnote style reference at the end of a beamer slide.  In the MWE below, I have used the `footcite` command, as per [References at the end of beamer slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147279/references-at-the-end-of-beamer-slides)
However, the author of that post himself mentions that this is just a hack and will not work in all cases.  In my specific case, I have exported my bibliography from Endnote to LaTeX as a text file (this is why I use `bibliography{example.txt}`).  I cannot convert example.txt to example.bib via a manual file extension conversion for some reason (probably because information is lost during the conversion when it's done by hand by changing .txt to .bib).  However, all entries of that text file are as they should be (i.e., all fields are present in the correct LaTeX formatting). What could be the problem?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\bibliography{example.txt}

\counterwithin*{footnote}{page}
\newcommand\footcite[1]{\footnote{\bibentry{#1}}\label{\thepage:#1}}
\newcommand\secondcite[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{\thepage:#1}}}

\begin{document}
Hello,World\footcite{Name2014}
\end{document}
```

P.S. I have tried creating my own custom text file with only one entry (as per [References at the end of beamer slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147279/references-at-the-end-of-beamer-slides)):

```
@book{Saussure1995,
    Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
    Origyear = {1916},
    Publisher = {Payot},
    Title = {Cours de Linguistique G{\'e}n{\'e}rale},
    Year = {1995}}
```

And changing the `footcite` command to `footcite{Saussure1995}`.  I have the exact same output produced as with the code block above, so clearly this is not a problem with my text file.

P.P.S. I have tried making a custom `.bib` file with just one entry with the following MWE below but I still get the same result:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\bibliography{example2.bib}

\counterwithin*{footnote}{page}
\newcommand\footcite[1]{\footnote{\bibentry{#1}}\label{\thepage:#1}}
\newcommand\secondcite[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{\thepage:#1}}}

\begin{document}
Hello,World\footcite{Saussure1995}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure I have understood what your problem is. However, here is a possible solution  using `biblatex` (and there is no need to change the extension of the bibliography file from `txt` to `bib`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}
  [\mkbibfootnote]
  {}
  {\usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {}
  {}

\addbibresource{apa-test-bib1.txt}

\counterwithin*{footnote}{page}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
Hello, World\footcite{Labov1972}

Hello, World\footcite{Saussure1995}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
Hello,World\footcite{Saussure1995}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: I'm not getting the full footnote citation below, I only get the footnote produced and the following text in bold-face: `Saussure1995.`  Both my text file and .tex file are in the same directory.

Comment: You have to compile with `biber` instead of `bibtex` (or alternatively, you can add `backend=bibtex` as one of the options of the `biblatex` package, i.e., `\usepackage[style=apa,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`

Comment: `\usepackage[style=apa,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` completely throws things off in the MWE above.

Comment: Yes, `biblatex-apa` requires `biber`, just checked  in its manual.

Comment: Any other suggestions?  I'm not sure what to put in my MWE above to get it to work with `biber` and hopefully you can provide some alternatives (e.g., `natbib`).

Comment: From the command line run `pdflatex <file>` then `biber <file>` and then `pdflatex <file>`. Otherwise see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations.  If you want to use `bibtex` you have to change the extension of the bibliography to `bib`.

Comment: Doing `biber <file>` gives `ERROR - Cannot find control file 'testing.tex.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?`.  Using `\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}` does not fix the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19838/discussion-between-guido-and-warship).

Answer (score 1):

The package `bibentry` requires to have a `\bibliography{<bib-file>}` or `\nobibliography{<bib-file>}` after the `\begin{document}`.

Thus a simple MWE should be:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}    
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

% filecontents to make the MWE self-contained.
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Saussure1995,
Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
Origyear = {1916},
Publisher = {Payot},
Title = {Cours de Linguistique G{\'e}n{\'e}rale},
Year = {1995}}

@book{Labov1972,
Address = {Philadelphia},
Author = {William Labov},
year = {1972},
Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
}
\end{filecontents}

\counterwithin*{footnote}{page}
\newcommand\footcite[1]{\footnote{\bibentry{#1}\label{\thepage:#1}}
\newcommand\secondcite[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{\thepage:#1}}}

\begin{document}
\nobibliography{\jobname}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
Hello,World \footcite{Labov1972}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

Comment: How are you getting this?  When I replace `apa-test-bib1` with the name of my own file, I just get a fatal error with no output whatsoever. Have you tested this code?  Neither the `bibliography{<bib-file>}` nor the `nobibliography{<bib-file>}` options work.

Comment: The screenshot has been created by compiling the MWE in the answer. So yes, it has been tested.  Normal workflow: `pdflatex <file> -> bibtex <file> -> pdflatex <file>`.

Comment: Can you please post what your `.bib` entry looks like?  It could be a problem with the entry formatting.

Comment: You should test your bib file with a standard document.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this question has been a real struggle (e.g., [Putting a bibliography citation at bottom of beamer slide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219982/putting-a-bibliography-citation-at-bottom-of-beamer-slide?noredirect=1#comment516652_219982)), here is a hack that I propose that I came up with thanks to a lot of trial and error (if someone could propose something else besides for this hack, I think that it would really help the community):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hello,World\footfullcite{Write something here, anything you like}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: biblatex footnote hack]

Please note that using `\footcite` in place of `\footfullcite` produces the same output.