# Putting a bibliography citation at bottom of beamer slide

Tags: beamer, bibtex

I read [Place bibliography items at bottom of frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5836/place-bibliography-items-at-bottom-of-frame) and tried making my own `.bib` file with just one entry.  The entry is nothing out of the ordinary:

```
@book{Saussure1995,
    Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
    Origyear = {1916},
    Publisher = {Payot},
    Title = {Cours de Linguistique G{\'e}n{\'e}rale},
    Year = {1995}}
```

However, when I try the MWE below, I don't actually get what [Place bibliography items at bottom of frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5836/place-bibliography-items-at-bottom-of-frame) shows, instead I just get `Saussure1995` (the label I used for my entry) in bold letters without any citation details whatsoever.  What could be the problem?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{example2}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hello,World\footfullcite{Saussure1995}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works out of the box with the standard `pdflatex biber pdflatex` workflow, and if you use `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` with the workflow `pdflatex bibtex pdflatex`.

Comment: @Guido Unfortunately, none of those options work (for some reason).

Comment: are you able to run `biber` from the command line? are you able to run bibtex on other "normal" documents?

Comment: @Guido Yes to both those questions.

Comment: Then it should work out of the box. I have created the MWE on WriteLaTeX to show it works without problems (https://www.overleaf.com/2054094zcffhs).  When you run biber\bibtex on the MWE what do you get in the log (`blg` file?). Can you also add  `\listfiles` to the MWE to get the version of the sty and close used.

Answer (score 2):

Answering this question has been a real struggle (e.g., [References at the end of beamer slides (Endnote export as text file)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219950/references-at-the-end-of-beamer-slides-endnote-export-as-text-file/219976?noredirect=1#comment516645_219976)), here is a hack that I propose that I came up with thanks to a lot of trial and error (if someone could propose something else besides for this hack, I think that it would really help the community):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hello,World\footfullcite{Write something here, anything you like}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: biblatex footnote hack]

Please note that using `\footcite` in place of `\footfullcite` produces the same output.

Answer (score 2):

What I do in these cases is this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
            doi=false,
            isbn=false,
            url=false,
            firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{calc}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\newcommand\FrameText[1]{%
\begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(\textwidth-\widthof{#1},0.92\textheight)\raggedright #1\hspace{0.5em}
\end{textblock*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\FrameText{\parencite{Saussure1995}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:
[image: test]