# Adding references in beamer slides

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I am adding references in slides created using `beamer`.Following the post in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147279/references-at-the-end-of-beamer-slides?rq=1) link
I made a few modifications. The line that appears in the footnote stops in the middle of the frame. How do we extend it until the end of the frame/ how to remove the line?

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table,dvipsnames,usenames}]{beamer}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Saussure1995,
    Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
    Origyear = {1916},
    Publisher = {Payot},
    Title = {Cours de Linguistique G{\'e}n{\'e}rale},
    Year = {1995}}

@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\counterwithin*{footnote}{page}
\newcommand\footcite[1]{\footnote{\bibentry{#1}}\label{\thepage:#1}}
\newcommand\secondcite[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{\thepage:#1}}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {image/} }
\begin{document}
\nobibliography{\jobname}
\subsection{frame 6}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=4cm]{rabbit.png}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=4cm]{rabbit.png}\footcite{Saussure1995}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{image/image.png}
\caption{Steps }
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Edit1: Also, for images how do we directly include the reference at the footnote without displaying the reference number next to the image.
[image]
Edit2: The size of the font in the footnote appears big. I tried reducing the size using `\tiny \footcite{Saussure1995}`. But this isn't reducing the font size. Any suggestions?

Edit3:Here is the code without `\subcaption` and without `figure`

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table,dvipsnames,usenames}]{beamer}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Saussure1995,
    Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
    Origyear = {1916},
    Publisher = {Payot},
    Title = {Cours de Linguistique G{\'e}n{\'e}rale},
    Year = {1995}}

@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin*{footnote}{page}
\newcommand\footcite[1]{\footnote{\bibentry{#1}}\label{\thepage:#1}}
\newcommand\secondcite[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{\thepage:#1}}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {image/} }
\begin{document}
\nobibliography{\jobname}
\subsection{frame 6}
\begin{frame}{}
\includegraphics[width=.47\textwidth]{rabbit.png}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.47\textwidth]{rabbit.png}\footcite{Saussure1995}
\vfill
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=50pt]{image.png}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{image/image.png}
\caption{Steps }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Edit5:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table,dvipsnames,usenames}]{beamer}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{aguiree2013idf,
  title={IDF diabetes atlas},
  author={Aguiree, Florencia and Brown, Alex and Cho, Nam Ho and Dahlquist, Gisela and Dodd, Sheree and Dunning, Trisha and Hirst, Michael and Hwang, Christopher and Magliano, Dianna and Patterson, Chris and others},
  year={2013},
  publisher={International Diabetes Federation}
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\nobibliography{\jobname}
\subsection{frame 6}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.47\textwidth]{image/rabbit.png}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.47\textwidth]{image/rabbit.png}
\vfill
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=50pt]{example-image}
\caption{Steps}
\end{figure}
\vfill
\footnotesize Image credit: \bibentry{aguiree2013idf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
 An error is displayed while compiling the above, citation not found.

Comment: Adding `\usepackage{subcaption}` changes the orientation of the images

Comment: If there is no number next to an image, how schould anyone know which image the footnote belongs to?

Comment: Is there a better way to display the number? It appears to the right and doesn't appear like a citation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Will your subfigures have captions? If so you could include the citation there. If not, why do you use the subfigure environment? In your previous question you were shown how to position the images without using `subfigure` or `figure`.

Comment: I can't compile your document if I load the `subcaption` package, are you sure about your ECM? Which compilation engine do you use?

Comment: @AndréC someone edited what I had originally posted to include `subcaption`. I'm using sharelatex

Comment: @leandriis I don't have captions for the subfigures. I have also included the code without `subfigure` or `figure`

Comment: Apologies, I should have asked, and not just edited. Your original example doesn't work at all, because the `subfigure` environment isn't defined by any of the packages you had (you get `! LaTeX Error: Environment subfigure undefined.`). `subcaption` does define an environment like that, used in the way you did, so I assumed that package was just missing. Edit: I see you do by accident get some reasonable output if you skip through that error, but the code is still wrong without `subcaption`.

Comment: (By the way, as far as I know it's possible to ping users who have edited a post as well, not just other commenters, so I think if you'd used @TorbjørnT. in your first comment, I would have been notified of it.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No issues and thank you very much for pointing out the mistakes that I have made. For some reason, I didn't face any problem in compiling the file with `subfigure`.

Comment: I think ShareLaTeX by default runs in nonstopmode, meaning latex will skip past any errors and try to generate some output. But ShareLaTeX tells you that there are errors with the small red box with the number in it, next to the compile button (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWddi.png). Whenever you get a red box like that there, you should click it to find out what the error is, and then try to find and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to remove the footnoterule and the footnotemark, why not manually placing the reference at the bottom of the frame?

Off-topic: but you cannot use `\caption` outside of a `figure` or `table` environment.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table,dvipsnames,usenames}]{beamer}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@article{aguiree2013idf,
  title={IDF diabetes atlas},
  author={Aguiree, Florencia and Brown, Alex and Cho, Nam Ho and Dahlquist, Gisela and Dodd, Sheree and Dunning, Trisha and Hirst, Michael and Hwang, Christopher and Magliano, Dianna and Patterson, Chris and others},
  year={2013},
  publisher={International Diabetes Federation}
}

\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\nobibliography{\jobname}
\subsection{frame 6}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.47\textwidth]{rabbit.png}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.47\textwidth]{rabbit.png}
\vfill
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=50pt]{example-image}
\caption{Steps}
\end{figure}
\vfill
\footnotesize Image credit: \bibentry{aguiree2013idf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Will this work for only specific bibliography style? For instance, I am using BibTeX format. An error is displayed while compiling, _citation not found_.

Comment: @Natasha Can you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that demonstrates the error you get?

Comment: Please check the edit 5 in my original post

Comment: @Natasha Does not completely fit on the page, because the reference is too long, but otherwise it works fine for me.

Comment: But,  my earlier version of the code displayed the output. I compiled the code that you updated in sharelatex.It doesn't display the same output.

Comment: Here is the link[https://www.sharelatex.com/read/xdxknhdfcgrr
]

Comment: @Natasha Your sharelatex document does not compile because it cannot find your rabbit image. Make life easier for everybody and use `example-image` for such test.

Comment: sorry about that. Still doesn't compile.

Comment: @Natasha Sharelatex uses some rather old package versions. They seem to have a problem with a subsection without section. Add a section to your code to circumvent the problem. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8ntt.png

Comment: As you advised, I have added a section. For some reason the reference doesn't appear in the footnote again

Comment: @Natasha If I visit your sharelatex link, I see a reference

Comment: I see only the Image credit text. The reference isn't there. I have also attached the snapshot of the same. Kindly suggest if there is any alternative

Comment: For some strange reason, I am not able to view the reference when I log in into my account. The reference is visible when I don't log in