# \footnote in table* environment

Tags: tables, footnotes, acm

I am using the `SIG-Alternate.cls - Version 2.5` template for my document. I want to have a `\footnote{...}` in a table. Because my table is very big I use the `table*` environment. The footnote also needs to have no number or mark whatsoever. What I have tried:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\begin{document}
% some text here
\begin{table*}
  \begin{tabular}
    % actual table
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Some caption text}
\end{table*}\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{$^*$The footnote text}
% some more text here
\end{document}
```

This results in having the footnote on the wrong page. Is there any way to make sure the footnote in on the same page as my 'whole page sized' table? I have another smaller table marked up in the same way, which is not on it's own page, but also with this table I am not able to have the footnote on the same page as the table.

If I put the `\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{$^*$The footnote text}` in the `tabular` environment, then there is no footnote at all.

Comment: How are your readers supposed that a markless footnote refers to the figure?

Comment: In the table cells I use $^*$ multiple times, so if I let the footer text start with $^*$ it would be clear.

Comment: It would be clearer if those explanations are in the caption.

Comment: That would make the caption very very long, thus I would still like the solution as I described in the question and not use this workaround.

Comment: nobody says that there can't be separate text in a `table` environment after the end of the `tabular`, not part of the caption.  also, it's usually more common for table captions to be above the table, but that's irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest you load the [threeparttable](http://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) package, especially as it seems to be fully compatible with the `sig-alternate` document class. The package's purpose is to allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment. The three parts of a `threeparttable` are `\caption`, the `tabular` (or `tabular*`, `tabularx`, etc) environment, and the `tablenotes` environment. The footnote marks can be almost anything you want, and footnote marks (say, an asterisk) can be repeated. A `threeparttable` environment should be encased in `table` or `table*` environment to make it "float" (in the LaTeX sense of the word, of course).

I would not recommend leaving off the footnote marks. However, it's entirely possible to do so. E.g., in the code below you'd leave off the `\tnote{*}` instructions inside the `tabular` environment and omit `[*]` after the first `\item` directive in the `tablenotes` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} % http://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
  \centering
  \caption{Tabular Material}
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \begin{tabular}{llll}
    \toprule
    123\tnote{*} & 456 & 789\tnote{*} & abc\tnote{a}\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}
  \item[*] The footnote text.
  \item[a] Another footnote.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The footnote is directly under the table, between the table and the caption. Though it would be nice to have it as a normal footnote in the footer of the page, but this looks nice as well. Thank you for your complete and clear example.

Comment: @martijnn2008 - If you want the caption to be at the bottom, below the table-related footnotes, just move the `\caption` command to some place *after* the `tablenotes` environment.

Comment: That is exactly how it is already. I mean the footnotes in the footer of the page, now it's directly under the table. In my example the `\caption` is also under the `\end{tabular}`.

Comment: How to make the footnote in this table environment appear as the normal footnote in the footer of the page?

Comment: @Tanvir - You pose a good question, but it's quite unrelated to the one posted here. This site works best if new questions are posed as, well, new postings.