# change align footnote in table

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have a Table with a footnote in it based on this post [\footnote in table* environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209802/footnote-in-table-environment)
and overall, I am happy with the Table's aspect, except that the footnote marker * is on the right part of the cell, but the number on the same cell is left-aligned. Is there any way to "join" them (left aligned them)
[image]

Thank you in advance,

My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4,BCOR=15mm,bibliography=totoc,DIV=9,final,headings=optiontohead,
listof=chaptergapsmall,listof=totoc,numbers=noenddot,openright,parskip=half,titlepage,twoside,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[automark,ilines]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[ngerman,english,]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb} % 'mathtools' loads 'amsmath'  
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[
    output-decimal-marker={.}, % decimal marker (german: , and english: .)
    range-phrase={~to~},        % for units 4 to 10 K
    range-units=single,     % it is 4 -- 10 K and not 4K - 10K
    retain-explicit-plus,   % \SI{1E+4}{} = 1E+04 in the text
    output-exponent-marker=\text{E}, % marker for \SI{1e-4}{} = 1E-04 in the text
]{siunitx}      
\usepackage[font={small,it}, labelfont=bf, textformat=period]{caption}  
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\npdecimalsign{.}
\nprounddigits{0}
\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.2pt} 
\sisetup{round-mode=places, round-precision=3, retain-zero-exponent} % new
\small
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular*}{   \textwidth}{m{0.8cm}|m{1.4cm}|n{5}{2}n{5}{2}n{5}{2}n{5}{2}n{5}{2}n{5}{2}n{5}{2}n{5}{2}n{5}{2}}
\toprule
\textbf{VR $\mathbf{[m^{3}]}$} & \textbf{Reactor} & \textbf{2010} & \textbf{2011} & \textbf{2012} & \textbf{2013} & \textbf{2014} & \textbf{2015} & \textbf{2016} & \textbf{2017} & \textbf{2018}  \\ \hline
22 & C210 & 14800\tnote{*} &   &   & 13953 &   &   & 13230 &   &    \\ \hline
22 & C211 & 14000 &   &   & 14375 &   &   & 15656 &   &    \\ \hline
20.9 & C250 &   & 15446 &   &   &   & 11385 &   &   & X  \\ \hline
                20.9 & C251 &   & 16185 &   &   &   & 11385 &   &   & X  \\ \hline
                14.1 & C221 & X &   &   & X &   &   & 10346 &   &     \\ \hline
                22 & C222 & X &   &   & \text{X(reg)} &   &   & 16386 &   &     \\ \hline
                  9.8 & C220 &   & X &   & X &   &   & 7163 &   &     \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[*] 13 \% of this weight is 5x5 mm pallets of the same catalyst.
\end{tablenotes}
\caption{Amount in kg charged to every reactor from year 2010 to 2018}
\label{tab:catalystamount}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is due to the specifier of this column: `n{5}{2}`, which reserves space for two decimal digits, which you don't have. So either use `n{5}{0}`, or use the `S` column, as `siunitx` has tools to handle this case.

Comment: Thanks! I changed to n{5}{0} and worked perfectly!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been solved by comment.