# This table is not running

Tags: tables

Hi I need some help running this table.

Here are my codes

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\hline \noalign{\smallskip} & mpg & mpg & mpg\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline \noalign{\smallskip}weight & -.0060087  & -294.196 & 4\\
 & \begin{footnotesize}(4.50)**\end{footnotesize} & \begin{footnotesize}(5.28)**\end{footnotesize}\\
\noalign{\smallskip}foreign &  & 1,767.292 & 5\\
& \begin{footnotesize}(4.50)**\end{footnotesize} & \begin{footnotesize}(5.28)**\end{footnotesize}\\
\noalign{\smallskip}foreign*weight &  &  & 1,767.292\\
 & \begin{footnotesize}\end{footnotesize} & \begin{footnotesize}(2.52)*\end{footnotesize}\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\_cons & 11,253.061 & 11,905.415 & 7\\
 & \begin{footnotesize}(9.61)**\end{footnotesize} & \begin{footnotesize}(10.28)**\end{footnotesize}\\
\noalign{\smallskip}$R^2$ & 0.22 & 0.28 & 7\\
$N$ & 74 & 74 & 7\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\end{tabular}\\
\smallskip\begin{footnotesize}\ * $p<0$.05; ** $p<0$.01\end{footnotesize}\\
\smallskip
\end{center}
```

Comment: with \begin{tabular}{lccc} it works

Comment: with \footnote{$p<0$.05} and \footnote{$p<0$.01} in text.

Comment: You have 4 columns in the `tabular`, but only specify 3 in `{lcc}`. For footnotes, see [Footnotes in tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1583/5764)

Comment: Thanks I figure it out, but now having problems adding a caption to the table.

Comment: \begin{table}[tbp]...\caption{tabular with footnote}\end{table}

Comment: @user36829: For a caption, set the entire `tabular` inside a `table` environment, not `center`. Also, read up on [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/5764)

Comment: You make it harder for people to help if you do not provide a complete document rather than a fragment. rather than use non-standard constructs such as `\noalign{\smallskip}\hline \noalign{\smallskip}` you may be better to use the `\booktabs` package and `\midrule` the booktabs rule automatically have some extra space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is. I need the `threeparttable` package for table notes, `makecell` to allow for line breaks in  tabular cells and a better spacing between rows. The code is more compact:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs, caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont = sc}
\renewcommand \cellalign{tc}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-digits = integer, group-separator = {,},group-four-digits}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{A Simple Table}\label{mylabel}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\toprule
& mpg & mpg & mpg\\
\midrule
weight & \makecell{\num[group-digits, group-separator=\,]{-.0060087}\\\footnotesize(4.50)\tnote{**}} & \makecell{\num{-294.196}\\\footnotesize(5.28)\tnote{**}} & 4\\
foreign & \makecell{\\\footnotesize(4.50)\tnote{**}} & \makecell{\num{1767.292}\\\footnotesize(5.28)\tnote{**}} & 5\\
foreign\tnote{*}\enspace weight & &\makecell{\\\footnotesize(2.52)\tnote{*}} & \num{1767.292}\\
\_cons & \makecell{\num{11253.061}\\\footnotesize(9.61)\tnote{**}} & \makecell{\num{11905.415}\\\footnotesize(10.28)\tnote{**}} & 7\\
$R^2$ & 0.22 & 0.28 & 7\\
$N$ & 74 & 74 & 7\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\smallskip\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[*]$p<0.05 $
\item[**]$p<0.01 $
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]