# footnotemark problem

Tags: tables, footnotes

My problem, footnote doesn't all appears. This question may be duplicate. But I don't find it. It doesn't work that I found questions. Where did I wrong?

```
...
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|r|}
\hline
{\bf D} & {\bf T} & {\bf U} & { \bf L} & {\bf S} & {\bf K} & {\bf AKTS\footnotemark} & {\bf N} & {\bf P}\\ \hline 
\multirow{9}{*}{C} &  A  &  A & A & A &  A & A & AA & B\\
& A & A & A & A & A & A & BA & B\\ \cline{2-9}
& A & A & A & A & A & A & BB & B\\ \cline{2-9}
& A & A & A & A & A & A & CB & B\\ \cline{2-9}
& A & A & A & A & A & A & CC & B\\ \cline{2-9}
& A & A & A & A & A & A & DC & B\\ \cline{2-9}
& A & A & A & A & A & A & DD & B\\ \cline{2-9}
& A & A & A & A & A & A & FD & B\\ \cline{2-9}
& A & A & A & A & A & A & FF & B\\ \cline{2-9}
\hline
\end {tabular}
\caption{Table}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\footnotetext{more more more bla bla ...}
```

[image]

Real footnote is,

[image]

Comment: Can you please show a complete compilable example which shows your problem?

Comment: Is there a reason for not keeping the footnote material together with the tabular material?

Comment: My MWE is long, too. But I'll try.

Comment: The footnote should be when the table is described in the text or at the bottom of the table. It doesn't make much sense to footnote the table itself. In my opinion, such a long footnote should be simply part of the text.

Comment: @egreg, I understand you.

Comment: I hope I don't do it bad that I paste link. Source code in>>> kisi.deu.edu.tr/cagdas.oz/latex/Problem.tar.gz <<< PDF in page 15 (Genel/derspolitikaları.tex).

Comment: @Özgür that isn't how the site works Please do not make external links, please make a small example, just delete everything not needed, you should be able to make a tex file of a few lines that shows whatever problem you have, so that people can trace it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, again I'll try.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, If it doesn't wrong, I will delete the question. I don't put MWE because It works there.

Comment: @Özgür you should make a MWE where it doesn't work:-) start with a copy of the document and delete everything you can delete while still showing the problem. Anyone trying to debug will have to do that, so it's better if you do it before posting

Comment: Off-topic: don't use `\bf`.

Comment: As reference, see [Footnotes in tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1583/5764)

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment and to bring this to an end:

With the following MWE everything works without error message or warnings and shows the complete footnote at the bottom of the page. Please see that I changed the outdated `\bf` to `\textbf`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext} % creates dummy text or dummy document
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\blindtext % dummy text before table

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|r|}
\hline
{\textbf D} & {\textbf T} & {\textbf U} & { \textbf L} & {\textbf S} & {\textbf K} & {\textbf AKTS\footnotemark} & {\textbf N} & {\textbf P}\\ \hline 
\multirow{9}{*}{C} &  A  &  A & A & A &  A & A & AA & B\\
& A & A & A & A & A & A & BA & B\\ \cline{2-9}
& A & A & A & A & A & A & BB & B\\ \cline{2-9}
& A & A & A & A & A & A & CB & B\\ \cline{2-9}
& A & A & A & A & A & A & CC & B\\ \cline{2-9}
& A & A & A & A & A & A & DC & B\\ \cline{2-9}
& A & A & A & A & A & A & DD & B\\ \cline{2-9}
& A & A & A & A & A & A & FD & B\\ \cline{2-9}
& A & A & A & A & A & A & FF & B\\ \cline{2-9}
\hline
\end {tabular}
\caption{Table}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\footnotetext{\blindtext}% more more more bla bla ...

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Now please copy this MWE and change it to recreate the error you got.  Use package `blindtext` for dummy text.