# Footnote missing when used with table, tabularx

Tags: tables, footnotes, tabularx

I'm using [fithesis3 class](https://github.com/Witiko/fithesis3) and I'm unable to get to work table + tabularx + footnotes + footnote references.

I have tried

- `\tablefootnote` - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35328
- `\scrextend` (`\footref`) - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74668
- Wrapping table in `\begin{minipage}` with `\usepackage{float}` and then `\begin{table}[H]`.

But no matter what I do, the footnote is either not displayed below the table or instead of footnote reference number there are only `??`.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[
  digital, %% digital / printed
  final,   %% draft / final
  nocover, %% cover / nocover
  12pt,    %% 10pt/ 11pt / 12pt
  table,   %% Causes the coloring of tables. table / notable
  nolof,     %% Prints the List of Figures. lof / nolof
  nolot,     %% Prints the List of Tables. lot / nolot
  oneside, %% oneside / twoside (generally oneside)
  %% More options are listed in the user guide at
  %% <http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fithesis/guide/mu/fi.pdf>.
]{fithesis3}
\usepackage[resetfonts]{cmap} %% We need to load the T2A font encoding
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}  %% to use the Cyrillic fonts with Russian texts.
\usepackage[
  main=english,czech
]{babel}
\usepackage{paratype} %% For non-Latin scripts, it may be necessary to load additional fonts:
\def\textrussian#1{{\usefont{T2A}{PTSerif-TLF}{m}{rm}#1}}
%% The following section sets up the bibliography.
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[              %% When typesetting the bibliography, the
  backend=biber,          %% `numeric` style will be used for the
  style=numeric,          %% entries and the `numeric-comp` style
  citestyle=numeric-comp, %% for the references to the entries. The
  sorting=none,           %% entries will be sorted in cite order.
  sortlocale=auto,         %% For more unformation about the available
  urldate=iso8601,   %% US date formatting
  date=iso8601,
  block=ragged,
]{biblatex}               %% `style`s and `citestyles`, see:
%% <http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf>.
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip} %% Add empty space between bibliography entries

\usepackage{makeidx}      %% The `makeidx` package contains
\makeindex                %% helper commands for index typesetting.
%% These additional packages are used within the document:
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}   %% description list
\setlist[description]{style=nextline}   %% description starts on a new line
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   %% raggedright in bibliography

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{scrextend}

%  Document Start
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
Start

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X | X | X |}
\hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text& cell2 & cell3\footnote{Global footnote\label{my-ref}} \\ \hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9\tablefootnote{Global tablefootnote\label{my-ref-2}} \\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text & cell5 & cell6\footref{my-ref-2} \\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text& cell2 & cell3 \\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text & cell5 & cell6 \\ \hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text& cell2 & cell3 \\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text & cell5 & cell6 \\ \hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text& cell2 & cell3 \\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text & cell5 & cell6 \\ \hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text& cell2 & cell3 \\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text & cell5 & cell6 \\ \hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Table Caption.}
\label{my-table-reference}
\end{table}

\newpage
END

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `parnotes`:

```
 \documentclass[
  digital, %% digital / printed
  final,   %% draft / final
  nocover, %% cover / nocover
  12pt,    %% 10pt/ 11pt / 12pt
  table,   %% Causes the coloring of tables. table / notable
  nolof,     %% Prints the List of Figures. lof / nolof
  nolot,     %% Prints the List of Tables. lot / nolot
  oneside, %% oneside / twoside (generally oneside)
  %% More options are listed in the user guide at
  %% <http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fithesis/guide/mu/fi.pdf>.
]{fithesis3}
\usepackage[resetfonts]{cmap} %% We need to load the T2A font encoding
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}  %% to use the Cyrillic fonts with Russian texts.
\usepackage[
  main=english,czech
]{babel}
\usepackage{paratype} %% For non-Latin scripts, it may be necessary to load additional fonts:
\def\textrussian#1{{\usefont{T2A}{PTSerif-TLF}{m}{rm}#1}}
%% The following section sets up the bibliography.
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[              %% When typesetting the bibliography, the
  backend=biber,          %% `numeric` style will be used for the
  style=numeric,          %% entries and the `numeric-comp` style
  citestyle=numeric-comp, %% for the references to the entries. The
  sorting=none,           %% entries will be sorted in cite order.
  sortlocale=auto,         %% For more unformation about the available
  urldate=iso8601,   %% US date formatting
  date=iso8601,
  block=ragged,
]{biblatex}               %% `style`s and `citestyles`, see:
%% <http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf>.
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip} %% Add empty space between bibliography entries

\usepackage{makeidx}      %% The `makeidx` package contains
\makeindex                %% helper commands for index typesetting.
%% These additional packages are used within the document:
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}   %% description list
\setlist[description]{style=nextline}   %% description starts on a new line
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   %% raggedright in bibliography

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[roman]{parnotes}


%  Document Start
\begin{document}
%\chapter{Introduction}
%Start

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X | X | X |}
\hline
cell1\parnote{Here is my first footnote} dummy text dummy text dummy text& cell2 & cell3\footnote{Global footnote\label{my-ref}} 
\\ \hline
cell7 & cell8\parnote{Here is my second footnote} & cell9\tablefootnote{Global tablefootnote\label{my-ref-2}} 
\\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text & cell5 & cell6\footref{my-ref-2} 
\\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text& cell2 & cell3 \\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text & cell5 & cell6 \\ \hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text& cell2 & cell3 \\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text & cell5 & cell6 \\ \hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text& cell2 & cell3 \\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text & cell5 & cell6 \\ \hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text& cell2 & cell3 \\ \hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text & cell5 & cell6 \\ \hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Table Caption.}
\parnotes
\label{my-table-reference}
\end{table}

\newpage
END

\end{document}
```

If you want a different numbering, you can try something like `\parnote[1]{bla}`